# How to compare a local Git branch with its remote branch

Tags: git, diff

How can I see the `diff` between a local branch and a remote branch?

Comment: This questions was asked again later. It has a nice answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935633/git-diff-between-remote-and-local-repo

Comment: example: git diff master origin/master (where master is local master branch and origin/master is remote master branch).

Comment: @klyngbaek, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33289679/8554766) in particular ;-)

Comment: I was originally trying `git diff HEAD origin/HEAD` which seems to point to a different remote branch than the one I intended. Using the full branch name works as expected.

Answer (score 820, accepted):

To update remote-tracking branches, you need to type `git fetch` first and then:

```
git diff <mainbranch_path> <remotebranch_path>
```

You can `git branch -a` to list all branches (local and remote) and then choose the branch name from the list (just remove `remotes/` from the remote branch name.

Example: `git diff main origin/main` (where "main" is the local main branch and "origin/main" is a remote, namely the origin and main branch.)

Comment: He may need a fetch before (`git fetch`)

Comment: That just shows a sneak into the changes in bash, is there any way to open all changes in an IDE like VS code?

Comment: @Harsh Phoujdar Add the below code in your .git/.gitconfig file          `[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" --diff --wait
    trustExitCode = false` Make sure your path to code.exe file is correct.

Comment: On VS Code there is the [Git Lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension that is very helpfull on this and many other ways. On new GitLens tab > Repositories: There is a list of all files changed by commits ahead with a side-by-side preview on click.

Comment: `git fetch` is not enough. It has to be `git fetch <remote> <branch>`, so, typically: `git fetch upstream main`.

Answer (score 1592):

```
git diff <local branch> <remote>/<remote branch>
```

For example, `git diff main origin/main`, or `git diff featureA origin/next`

Of course to **have** said *remote-tracking branch* you need to `git fetch` first; and you need it to have up-to-date information about branches in the remote repository.

Comment: to be more exact: git diff <local branch> <remote>/<remote branch>

Comment: I usually do `git diff <remote>/<remote branch> <local branch>` to see what my push will do to remote repo.

Comment: The even shorter `git diff origin` is sufficient if you just compare with your upstream branch.

Comment: please add `git fetch` at the beginning,it cause trouble to newbie like me

Comment: The `git branch -a` below really completes the picture. It shows you all of your remote branches, for easy diff'ing.

Comment: Hey, shouldn't it be `git diff <remote>/<remote branch> <local branch>`? Otherwise, I get the adds and deletes switched on my computer (git version 2.7.0.windows.2)

Comment: @Ludder, I think you meant `git diff @{upstream}` instead?

`git diff origin` always shows me `origin/master` no matter what branch I have checked out.

Comment: `origin` expands to the default branch, not the tracked branch.

Comment: @carej and @NielsKeurentjes: `origin` expands to what `origin/HEAD` points to, i.e. default branch; you can change where `origin` as a branch shortcut points to with the `git remote` command (in modern Git).

Comment: `git diff master origin/master` will only show differences if they have been committed, `git diff origin` or `git diff @{upstream}` will show differences even if they have not been committed.

Comment: Order matters. For ex., `git diff master origin/master` will show, what difference is present in remote file (compared to local _commited_ file), while `git diff origin/master master` will show, what difference is present in file from local repository (ie, commited) compared to remote file. And `git diff origin` is the same as `git diff origin/master master` **+** uncommited changes.

Comment: if you have some branch in two different remotes, you can compare them using `git diff <remote_1>/<branch_name> <remote_2>/<branch_name>`

Answer (score 270):

If you're on a given branch, and you want to compare your ***working copy*** with the upstream branch you're tracking, use:

```sh
git diff @{upstream}
```

If you want to compare ***your current HEAD*** with the upstream branch (thanks **@Arijoon**):

```sh
git diff @ @{upstream}
```

***If your upstream isn't set***, you can use `@{push}` to get a diff against the branch you are set to push to (also from **@Arijoon**'s comment):

```sh
git diff @{push}
```

Courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17766249/38765), the git documentation for [specifying revisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions) has:

> `<branchname>@{upstream}`, e.g. `master@{upstream}`, `@{u}`
> The suffix
> `@{upstream}` to a branchname (short form `<branchname>@{u}`) refers to
> the branch that the branch specified by `branchname` is set to build on
> top of (configured with `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge`).
> A missing `branchname` defaults to the current one.

Comment: Very good answer just missing a little part. Change the line to `git diff @ @{upstream}`. The extra `@` is `HEAD`, which is where you are now, so you are comparing `HEAD` with the upstream your branch is tracking. You can use `@{push}` instead of upstream to get diff between the branch you are set to push to

Comment: best answer, doesn't require fetching the remote. needs more upvotes!

Comment: In fish shell I got result: `fatal: ambiguous argument '@upstream': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`. Had to use `git diff @\{upstream\}` instead. 

Comment: You need to `git fetch` first, else this does nothing, shows no output; tested by deleting a file in the repo origin and ran this command locally. ..works only after fetch.

Comment: Also, as the answer as given includes any local changes. sometimes this is desired, other times, not.

Comment: `fatal: ambiguous argument '@{origin}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`. Based on comment above about problem with fish *(I'm on zsh though)*, I made it to somewhat work as `git diff @\\{origin\\}`. However the diff was empty, even though I changed one commit and I know it shouldn't be. So no, this answer doesn't work at all.

Comment: `fish`/`zsh`, comment the argument with single quotes so that no shell replacement happens. i.e. `git diff @ '@{u}'`. Read the shell manual to understand the replacment rules for your shell. Quoting with single quotes will work in _all_ shells though.

Comment: If you want to view the diff for the current HEAD from the perspective of "what did I add/remove/change that isn't yet on the remote" (i.e. a new file shows up as additions not subtractions), just switch the order: `git diff @{upstream} @`

Comment: The other answers are good, but i find this one easiest to work with using git hooks since it doesn't require a bunch of extra steps for branch names. `@{push}` specifically is the piece I'm using.

Comment: `git diff @{upstream}` solves my need. I just added an alias to my .gitconfig `diffu = diff @{upstream}`

Answer (score 210):

First type

```
git branch -a
```

to get the list of available branches. On the output you may see something like

```
* master
  remotes/main/master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mt
  remotes/upstream/master
  remotes/upstream/mt
```

Then show the diff

```
git diff --stat --color remotes/main/master..origin/master
git diff remotes/main/master..origin/master
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `...` rather than `..`?

Comment: I would definitely have chosen this as the answer. Following your directions, I was able to view the differences between a local branch and a remote branch. Thanks!

Comment: I usually do `git log origin/my_branch..` which will take `HEAD` as local ref, which is mostly what you mean.

Comment: +1 for best answer in my humble opinion. Would be worthy of +2 if you mentioned "fetch" to synchronize the "remote" image of the cloned source. The stat/color overview step is particularly helpful.

Comment: As diff is about two endpoints, and not about revision range like log, therefore `git diff A..B` is `git diff A B`, and `git diff A...B` is `git diff $(git merge-base A B) B` - the syntax is to make it possible to copy'n'paste `git fetch` output both to `git log` and `git diff`.

Comment: Why dots at all between the branches being diff'd? Is that any different than just using a space? Edit: documentation is at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Comment: Thanks for the one answer that finally worked out of the seven or eight "answers" that resulted in little more than `fatal: bad revision` or `fatal: ambiguous argument`. All I wanted was to see the diff on the same file from another branch, was that too much to ask? Yes, yes it was. :-) `git diff remotes/origin/<base branch> <current branch> -- <filename>` works great on git 1.8.3.1

Comment: This is the better answer. The previous answers are too abstract and do not include the exploratory first step.

Comment: Can you respond to [Eliran Malka's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/how-to-compare-a-local-git-branch-with-its-remote-branch#comment22638957_10130388)?

Comment: Do the examples really use a local branch (as in the question)? Can you elaborate [in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10130388/edit)?

Comment: Why do the examples include "origin/"? Shouldn't it be left out? Can you elaborate in your answer?

Comment: Can someone rewrite this for main instead of master? I'm not having success just changing the word master to main

Answer (score 48):

I understand much better the output of:

*`git diff <remote-tracking branch> <local branch>`*

That shows me what is going to be dropped and what is going to be added if I push the local branch. Of course it is the same, just the inverse, but for me it is more readable, and I'm more comfortable looking at what is going to happen.

Comment: I get exactly the same result with:

git diff <local branch> <remote-tracking branch>
or
git diff <remote-tracking branch> <local branch>

Answer (score 35):

The easy way:

```
git fetch
git log -p HEAD..FETCH_HEAD
```

This will first fetch the changes from your default remote (origin). This will be created automatically when you clone a repository. You can also be explicit: `git fetch origin master`.

Then `git log` is used to compare your current branch with the one just fetched. (The `-p` (generate patch) option is what shows the *differences*.)

Comment: Doesn't work to detect your local new commits.

Answer (score 26):

**TLDR**: `git diff <local branch> <remote branch>`

When using Git in the shell, I like to first orient myself by looking around.

Here's a command to **show all branches**

```
$ git branch -a  # (or git branch --all)
* my-branch
  master
  remotes/origin/some-branch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/my-branch
  remotes/origin/some-other-branch
  remotes/origin/master
```

Here I have two local branches (`my-branch` and `master`) and four remote branches (`some-branch`, `some-other-branch`, `master`, and `my-branch`).

Also, the asterisk next to `my-branch` signals the fact that I'm currently in that branch (you would also know that by using the command `git status` that would output: `On branch my-branch.`).

*Note: the remote branches in the [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) shell are shown in red while the local ones are shown in green.*

If you just want to **show remote branches**:

```
$ git branch -r # (or git branch --remotes)
  origin/some-branch
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/my-branch
  origin/some-other-branch
  origin/master
```

*To show just local branches you might be tempted to use `git branch -l`, but that's a completely different command.* To **show local branches** use `git branch` with no options

```
$ git branch
* my-branch
  master
```

To complete a review of the basic branch options, there's the `--list` that, contrary to what you might expect, is there to allow **filtering**. Use it with a pattern like this:

```
$ git branch --list 'my*'
* my-branch
```

You can also combine `--list` with the options `-a` and `-r`, but make sure to adapt your pattern accordingly (*remember: remote branches start with "remotes"*).

Example:

```
# This will show all branches (local & remote) that start with my
$ git branch --list 'my*' -a
* my-branch

# Better: the pattern includes the remote
$ git branch --list '*my*' -a
* my-branch
  remotes/origin/my-branch
```

Documentation: *[git-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)*

Now you can **compare any two branches** from all the available ones (you can also compare two locals or two remotes).

Here I'm comparing the local with the remote `my-branch`. They're synchronized, so I don't get any output:

```
$ git diff my-branch remotes/origin/my-branch
```

*Note: you have to give the full names of the branches with no quotation marks.*

I can also compare the local `my-branch` to the remote `master`. Here I get some output, because the remote `my-branch` hasn't been merged into the master branch.

```
$ git diff my-branch remotes/origin/master
diff --git a/src/controllers/call.controller.js b/src/controllers/call.controller.js
index fd79b98..df3d798 100644
--- a/src/controllers/call.controller.js
+++ b/src/controllers/call.controller.js
@@ -261,7 +261,7 @@ function callController() {
   /*
    *  Function: doCall
[ . . . ]
```

Answer (score 19):

This is how I do it.

```
# To update your local.
git fetch --all
```

This will fetch everything from the remote, so when you check difference, it will compare the difference with the remote branch.

```
# To list all branches
git branch -a
```

The above command will display all the branches.

```
# To go to the branch you want to check difference
git checkout <branch_name>
# To check on which branch you are in, use
git branch
    (or)
git status
```

Now, you can check the differences as follows.

```
git diff origin/<branch_name>
```

This will compare your local branch with the remote branch.

Comment: git fetch --all will fetch everything from ALL remotes. git fetch should be sufficient if you use the default origin remote.

Comment: Amazing that after 8 years, we get a complete answer that properly explains the steps.  We can do a --help to get the commands.  SO is about understanding them.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a shorthand answer if you are comparing your current branch and to something you want to `git pull`.

```
git fetch
git diff FETCH_HEAD
```

The first command will figure out which remote branch corresponds to your current branch. An artefact of that calculation in the `FETCH_HEAD` reference. Then the second command uses that reference to compare versus what your current branch has.

Comment: Great, `FETCH_HEAD` is exactly what I was missing. Just a small detail: in case you want to take the last local commit as baseline and see what has changed in origin, run `git diff HEAD FETCH_HEAD`

Answer (score 13):

Let your working branch be *development* and you want to differentiate between the local development branch and the remote development branch. In that case, the syntax should be like:

```
git diff remotes/origin/development..development
```

Or

```
git fetch origin
git diff origin/development
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to see the difference as just the names of the files changed then use:

```
git diff --name-status <remote-branch> <local-branch>
```

Else this would show all differences between the two branches:

```
git diff <remote-branch> <local-branch>
```

Comment: Does this require a Git fetch or not? Why or why not? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40375132/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 9):

In my case I have a second remote called `heroku` that is **not** the `origin` and because it wasn't in sync, I got this error when trying to run the `git diff master heroku/master`:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'heroku/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Or this when trying the other approach `git diff master..heroku/master`:

> fatal: bad revision 'master..heroku/master'

The solution was explicitly mentioning the remote name in `git fetch` before running `git diff`, in my case:

```
$ git fetch heroku
$ git diff master heroku/master
```

Answer (score 5):

```
git difftool <commit> .
```

This will compare the commit you want with your local files. Don't forget the dot in the end (for local).

For example, to compare your local files with some commit:

> git difftool 1db1ef2490733c1877ad0fb5e8536d2935566341 .

(and you don't need git fetch, unless comparing to new commits is needed)

Comment: I think tis is interesting because is a comparison I can make before commit and push. Unfortunately in windows vimdiff for showing is ugly; is there any way to use anything better, like notepad++?

Answer (score 5):

First thing you need to do is run:

**`git fetch`** on your local branch

if you see changes in console result like :

```
'diff --git a/versions.txt b/versions.txt
 index 82d6379..794e6c7 100644
 --- a/versions.txt
 +++ b/versions.txt
 @@ -9,3 +9,4 @@ version8
 version 9 let it fetch yes
 let see changes ok ?
 another line
 +second line^M'
```

, that's mean that there are changes in that remote repo that aren't in your local one, you can check remote repositorie is ahead of local repositorie using:

**`git log origin/master`**

**git log remote repo/local repo**

now run :
**`git diff master origin/master`**

**git diff localRepo remoteRepo/localRepo**
so you can see the difference

> note that running : git log origin/master as first step will not show
> if there are changes or not, you must fetch first

then you can pull those changes into your local repositorie
using :

**`git pull origin master`**

**git pull remoteRepo localRepo**

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
git diff origin HEAD
```

Assuming you want to diff you current *local* branch's `HEAD` against the origin.
And assuming you are on the local branch. :)

Comment: I tried this 5 minutes ago and it's still scrolling through, having decided that every single file in my project is different

Comment: I tried but it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

A convenient one-liner for diffing the current branch with its state in the remote (i.e. how to answer the question "what's going to change when I push?") as follows:

`git diff origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)`

Answer (score 2):

I wonder about if there is any change in my **master** branch...

1. Firstly, you need to change your branch (If you are already under this branch, you do not need to do this!):

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
2. You can see which file has been modified under your master branch by this command:

   ```
   git status
   ```
3. List the branches

   ```
   git branch -a
   ```

   > - master 
   >   remotes/origin/master
4. Find the differences

   ```
   git diff origin/master
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I kept seeing this error

```
git diff main origin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Solution: I had to `git push` first (since *both* the remote and local need to be up to date), and *then* this worked:

```sh
git diff master origin/master
```

Comment: But then both local and remote are up to date and there's no delta? Doesn't that defeat the point of the diff?

Comment: @Owl I think you're right. I have no idea what I was doing at the time, but looking at the code I ran that produced the error, I suspect I may have tried `main` on an older repo that didn't have a branch called main (just `master`). But I'm just guessing. In all honesty I would ignore my answer here. I will consider deleting it as I can't see it actually helping.

Comment: i don't blame you at all though, it's obvious what you meant in your first command, not sure why git couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
git diff 'master' 'testlocalBranch'
```

If you are using an editor like [WebStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#WebStorm), you can right click on a file, select compare with branch, and type/select your branch.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does this add over the 7.5 year old accepted answer with 170+ upvotes?

Comment: This is For mrblah the user or for similar users who added comment for the accepted answer. Syntax is different from an example and example helps more from beginner's point of view.

Comment: In that case, it should be in comment of that answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple. You can use: `git diff remote/my_topic_branch my_topic_branch`

Where `my_topic_branch` is your topic branch.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW you can use the `--compact-summary` option.

`man git diff`

> Output a condensed summary of extended header information such as file creations or deletions ("new" or "gone", optionally "+l" if it’s a symlink) and mode changes ("+x" or "-x" for
> adding or removing executable bit respectively) in diffstat. The information is put between the filename part and the graph part. Implies --stat.

e.g.

```sh
git diff $(current_branch) origin/$(current_branch)
```

Comment: In case anyone else sees this answer, I needed to swap the positions of current branch and origin/current_branch. Using the command as-is, if you had added files to your current local branch, those files wouldn't be reflected in the diff.  `git diff origin/main $(git branch --show-current) `

Answer (score 0):

First you'll have to `git switch` to your desired branch in local and then perform `git fetch` so that your remote tracking branch will be in sync with your remote.
Then perform `git diff` ,for example -

```
git diff main origin/main
```

Once you're satisfied with the differences and ready to accept, then you can merge them using `git pull` .Usually I would prefer to do rebase in these kind of circumstances to avoid unnecessary commits -

```
git pull --rebase
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything (new) to the question that was asked.

Answer (score -1):

## Setup

`git config alias.udiff  'diff @{u}'`

## Diffing HEAD with HEAD@{upstream}

```
git fetch  # Do this if you want to compare with the network state of upstream; if the current local state is enough, you can skip this
git udiff
```

## Diffing with an Arbitrary Remote Branch

This answers the question in your heading ("its remote"); if you want to diff against "a remote" (that isn't configured as the upstream for the branch), you need to target it directly.  You can see all remote branches with the following:

`git branch -r`

You can see all configured remotes with the following:

`git remote show`

You can see the branch/tracking configuration for a single remote (e.g. origin) as follows:

`git remote show origin`

Once you determine the appropriate origin branch, just do a normal diff :)

`git diff [MY_LOCAL] MY_REMOTE_BRANCH`

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have already set up your `origin` as the remote repository. Then,

`git diff <local branch> <origin>/<remote branch name>`

Answer (score -2):

In [Visual Studio 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2019), just do *fetch*. Do not *pull* code.

This is what I did. I added the below in the *.gitconfig* file so that I can use [Beyond Compare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Compare)

```
File location: C:\Users\[username]\.gitconfig
```

Added below

```
[diff]
    tool = bc
[difftool "bc"]
    path = c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe
```

Open a command prompt and go to the working directory. I gave the below to compare the local *dev* branch to the remote *dev* branch:

```
git difftool dev origin/dev --dir-diff
```

This will open Beyond Compare and open directories which have files that differ. If there aren't any changes, Beyond Compare will not launch.

Comment: why -2 votes for this? hmmm