# How to check real git diff before merging from remote branch?

Tags: git, diff

I want to check the real diff between remote branch and local branch. How can I do that?

Issuing the below command partially works, but it shows the diff of the new changes of my local branch too.

```
git diff remote/branch
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. The diff shows you the difference between branches, why do you think they will not merge?

Comment: @Abizern my bad! I corrected the question. Thanks! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [compare local git branch with remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/compare-local-git-branch-with-remote-branch)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html):

> ```
> git diff [--options] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>…]
> ```
>
> This form is to view the changes on
>   the branch containing and up to the
>   second `<commit>`, starting at a common
>   ancestor of both `<commit>`. "git diff
>   A...B" is equivalent to "git diff
>   $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can omit
>   any one of `<commit>`, which has the
>   same effect as using HEAD instead.

did you try this?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize three dots works for this, It works! :)

Comment: This is definitely correct as far as `diff`, but if I replace by `log`, I get some commits in the list that bring changes that were invisible with `diff`. Those commits are ancestors of `A` that are unreachable from `B`; they are the development on my branch which I precisely do not care about, rather, I want to know what happens from `$(git-merge-base A B)` up to `B`. Why such a difference in behavior ?

Comment: Okay, this is not so straight forward but one gets there.
`A..B` shows the stuff that is accessible from `B` but not from `A` i.e. what is unique to `B` (what interest you in you are working on `A` and want to merge `B`)

Answer (score 156):

Since this topic comes up frequently, and can be confusing without a bit of background on how git works, I thought I'd try to explain the simplest case possible, but with sufficient depth that newcomers will have enough of a handle on it to do additional research.

If you set up your git repository via a normal 'clone' and have the default refspecs, meaning that your remote is named 'origin' and you pull/fetch from the branch 'master', you may sometimes need to see what's in the remote repository before pulling it down.

Since the "git pull" does an automatic merge (unless there are conflicts), it can be nice to see what's "incoming" next.   If you're not familiar with how git works, and how refspecs in particular are managed, this can be a bit non-intuitive.

Suppose someone makes a change in the remote repository **(for sake of illustration, adding a line to the remote repository by committing a change and pushing it)**, and you type:

```
$ git diff origin/master
```

You probably won't see any changes; however if you do the following:

```
$ git fetch; git diff ..origin/master
```

you'll see the difference between what's been committed to your local git repository and what's in the remote repository.  You will NOT see any changes which are in your local filesystem or staged in your index.

Ok, why do we do this?  origin/master is a **refspec** (see man pages).  In short, this is what we refer to in order to compare against, pull or fetch from, and push to.   All of the following are functionally equivalent:

```
origin/master
remotes/origin/master
refs/remotes/origin/master
```

To begin to untangle this, just take a peek at your repository's .git directory structure.  A typical layout looks like this:

```
.git/refs
.git/refs/heads
.git/refs/heads/master
.git/refs/remotes
.git/refs/remotes/origin
.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
.git/refs/remotes/origin/master
.git/refs/tags
```

Look at .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD; in the default case it will point to the branch you use to pull from and push to.  In my case, since I'm on master, the contents of this text file look like this:

```
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

This tells me that the HEAD of my remote is identified by the refspec 'refs/remotes/origin/master'(which happens to have the aliases mentioned above).

This doesn't tell us much; what's the state of the remote repository?  Look at the state of the remote master:

```
$ cat .git/refs/heads/master     
6d0fb0adfdfa5af861931bb06d34100b349f1d63
```

Ok, it's a SHA1 hash; probably a commit.  How does it get put in this file?  Well, whenever you do a pull or a fetch, this file is updated with the most recent commit from the remote which was pulled or fetched.  This explains why we have to `git fetch` prior to performing the diff.  Remember, `git fetch` just updates your local copy of a remote branch, but doesn't merge it with your working copy.  It is completely safe. A `git fetch; git merge` is equivalent to a `git pull`.

Once you do the fetch, git will be able to see the most recent commit in the remote 
repository as of the time of the fetch.

You can use various combinations of specifiers to git to see your diffs as you desire (the following examples use the local working copy as the implicit first commit):

```
$ git diff remote/origin   
This shows the incoming remote additions as deletions; any additions in your local 
repository are shown as additions.

$ git diff ...remote/origin
Shows incoming remote additions as additions; the triple-dot excludes changes
committed to your local repository.

$ git diff ..remote/origin
Shows incoming remote additions as additions; the double-dot includes changes
committed to your local repository as deletions (since they are not yet pushed).
```

For info on ".." vs "..." see `git help diff` as well as the excellent documentation at [git-scm revision selection: commit ranges](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges)  Briefly, for the examples above, double-dot syntax shows all commits reachable from origin/master but not your working copy.  Likewise, the triple-dot syntax shows all the commits reachable from either commit (implicit working copy, remote/origin) but not from both.

I'm going through this step by step because I'm fairly new to git and this is exactly the type of thing that had *me* confused... I'm sure that git experts can find flaws with the details... I just hope this answer bridges the gap for some people who find all the various posts a bit terse.

Comment: Double-dots and triple-dots, eh? That's kind of hideous. But thanks for your answer - it explains why git diff never showed much for me.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer; much more beginner-friendly and explains the important concepts around diff (the man-page is a pain to understand properly if you're not used to all the terms).

Comment: I don't understand the last part. "Shows incoming remote changes as additions"? So whether the incoming changes are additions or deletions, they're shown as additions? I don't believe that. The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/git-diff-whats-the-difference-between-having-and-no-dots) also seems quite different.

Comment: @Cerran I don't have the example in front of me, but this should be correct for the example provided.  If you try it and this is not true, please let me know.  If you're referring to the 'git diff ..remote/origin', you are comparing the current working copy with what's on the remote.  In this example, we're assuming that there are remote changes that don't exist in the current working copy (and that there are no changes in the working copy that don't exist on the remote).  The remote has things you do not... hence those changes show as additions.  Other invocations may do otherwise.

Comment: I'm talking about the following situation: Delete a line in a file, commit it, and push it to origin/master. In another repository (with the same origin), execute `git fetch` and then `git diff origin/master`. The deletion is shown as an addition; with two or three dots, it's shown as a deletion. I chose this command because `git diff remote/origin` always results in an error for me: fatal: ambiguous argument 'remote/origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this: 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: The point I'm making is just that it's not true to make statements like "changes are shown as additions". It really depends on what kind of change we're talking about. There are three kinds of changes: 1) new lines, which are typically shown as additions, 2) deleted lines, which are typically shown as deletions, and 3) modified lines, which are typically shown as the deletion of the old content AND the addition of the new content. I say "typically" because, as your examples show, it is possible to reverse this situation so that all three cases act oppositely of what I've just described.

Comment: @Cerran Yes you're right I underspecified the example, it seems.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Nice, I think you've already made it clearer than before, although a few parts are still not quite right: A) "any commits in your local 
repository are shown as additions"; B) "the double-dot includes changes committed to your local repository as deletions". I think I know what you mean to say here, though.

Comment: and for a specific file: git diff ..origin/master file-name

Answer (score 10):

What you want to do is, as suggested by Evgen Bodunov:

```
git diff ...remote/branch
```

This will diff changes from remote/branch and ignore changes from your current HEAD.