# What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git diff commit ranges?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

What are the differences between the following commands?:

```bash
git diff foo master   # a 
git diff foo..master  # b
git diff foo...master # c
```

[The diff manual](http://jk.gs/git-diff.html#_examples) talks about it:

> Comparing branches
>
> ```
> $ git diff topic master    <1>
> $ git diff topic..master   <2>
> $ git diff topic...master  <3>
> ```
>
> 1. Changes between the tips of the topic and the master branches.
> 2. Same as above.
> 3. Changes that occurred on the master branch since when the topic branch was started off it.

but isn't totally clear to me.

Answer (score 446, accepted):

*Since I'd already created these images, I thought it might be worth using them in another answer, although the description of the difference between `..` (dot-dot) and `...` (dot-dot-dot) is essentially the same as in [manojlds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/git-diff-whats-the-difference-between-having-and-no-dots/7252067#7252067).*

The command `git diff` typically¹ only shows you the difference between the states of the tree between exactly two points in the commit graph.  The `..` and `...` notations in `git diff` have the following meanings:

```bash
# Left side in the illustration below:
git diff foo..bar
git diff foo bar  # same thing as above

# Right side in the illustration below:
git diff foo...bar
git diff $(git merge-base foo bar) bar  # same thing as above
```

[image: An illustration of the different ways of specifying commits for git diff]

In other words, `git diff foo..bar` is exactly the same as `git diff foo bar`; both will show you the difference between the tips of the two branches `foo` and `bar`.  On the other hand, `git diff foo...bar` will show you the difference between the "merge base" of the two branches and the tip of `bar`.  The "merge base" is usually the last commit in common between those two branches, so this command will show you the changes that your work on `bar` has introduced, while ignoring everything that has been done on `foo` in the mean time.

That's all you need to know about the `..` and `...` notations in `git diff`.  However...

---

... a common source of confusion here is that `..` and `...` mean subtly different things when used in a command such as `git log` that expects a set of commits as one or more arguments.  (These commands all end up using [`git rev-list`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) to parse a list of commits from their arguments.)

The meaning of `..` and `...` for `git log` can be shown graphically as below:

[image: An illustration of the different ways of specifying ranges of commits for git log]

So, `git rev-list foo..bar` shows you everything on branch `bar` that isn't also on branch `foo`.  On the other hand, `git rev-list foo...bar` shows you all the commits that are in either `foo` *or* `bar`, but *not both*.  The third diagram just shows that if you list the two branches, you get the commits that are in either one or both of them.

Well, I find that all a bit confusing, anyway, and I think the commit graph diagrams help :)

¹ I only say "typically" since when resolving merge conflicts, for example, `git diff` will show you a three-way merge.

Comment: I like your diagrams. [I came up with my own a while ago too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/456814). I have some ideas for my own `git diff` diagrams that I'll make later.

Comment: Did someone notice? The effects of `..` and `...` feel _reversed_ in `git diff` (compared to `git rev-list`)!

Comment: You had me at "That's all you need to know [...]. However...". :-) Git is full of things like this where similar notation and terminology means different things in different contexts; thanks for clarifying this so well.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning rev-list. I came across this question while looking for a way of doing what rev-list does via rev-parse.

Comment: "In other words, `git diff foo..bar` is exactly the same as `git diff foo bar`; both will show you the difference between the tips of the two branches foo and bar." What exactly do you mean by the "difference between the tips of the two branches"?

Comment: What about when you do git rev-list sha1..sha2 on the same branch?  What would be the difference then between that and sha1...sha2?

Comment: What is `^` in the `git rev-list bar ^foor`?

Comment: @foxiris When `^` comes just before something that refers to a commit, it means "not". So `git rev-list bar ^foo` means "everything that is in bar, except for anything in `foo`"

Answer (score 109):

My consolidated version of the `..` vs `...` with **diff** vs **log**

[image: Diff vs Log & .. vs ..]

Comment: this would be very good, if only it didn't have so many different colors and set operations mixed up together with `..`/`...` stuff. For example in `log A...B` it is not clear whether the command returns the intersection (white part of the diagram) or the rest of the A-B union (green). It would be more to the point without any set operands and with only 1 color.

Comment: Should this really be `diff A..B` <—> `log A...B`, that is, does really *diff* with 2 dots, correspond to *log* with 3 (!) dots?  Or is there a typo in the image. Looking at how the dots are color coded, seems to me there's a typo in the image. The lower left corner: `log A...B` should be `log A..B`, right (?). And *log* just to the right should be `...` not `..`.

Comment: Hi DolphinDream, thanks for your figure. I use it as reference here: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/3427#note_227200695

Comment: @KajMagnus actually the red/blue colors are just used to distinguish between 2-dots and 3-dots (regardless of being used with diff or log). The diagram is correct. In the first column, the result of diff with 2-dots is similar to the log with 3-dots (hence the whole purpose diagram to begin with). The diff with 2-dots gives the code changes in both revs down to the divergence point (illustrated by the green bubbles around the commits and the green parts of the van diagrams) while log with 3-dots gives the change logs (commit messages) in both revs down to the divergence point.

Comment: Is there a mnemonic for this difference between `A B`, `A..B` and `A...B` for `diff` and `log`? How does it make sense, or how is it logically explainable? For `log` I think it's a bit easier than for `diff`, but it's just hard to come up with it naturally for all six cases.

Comment: @KajMagnus It seems confusing and contradictory because `git log` and `git diff` both treat `...` differently. _log_ uses gitrevisions (see `man 7 gitrevisions`) to parse the `...`, but _diff_ doesn't. _diff_ uses its own definition of `...` that is different from the one used by gitrevisions.

Comment: unrelated: Hey @DolphinDream how did you make this diagram? I'd like to learn how to make such diagrams. Any tips?

Comment: @snath03 It’s been awhile, but I think I used LibreOffice Draw to make it.

Comment: @xealits, the coloring makes sense to me: the `git log` "operator" is green, hence its operation result set is colored green (in the Venn diagrams, as well as in the graph diagrams).

Comment: @xealits personally I love the colours, the diagram is gorgeous and makes very good use of specific colours to link the venn diagrams and the parts of the tree.

Answer (score 38):

`git diff foo master` Diff between the tip (head) commits of `foo` and `master`.

`git diff foo..master` Another way of doing the same thing.

`git diff foo...master` Diff from the *common ancestor* (`git merge-base foo master`) of `foo` and `master` to the tip of `master`. In other words, it shows only the changes that `master` branch has introduced since its *common ancestor* with `foo`.

This [Learn.GitHub "what a merge would introduce" example (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20110807194518/http://learn.github.com/p/diff.html#what_a_merge_would_introduce) explains when to use the two:

> For instance, if you create a ‘dev’ branch and add a function to a
> file, then go back to your ‘master’ branch and remove a line from the
> README, and then run something like this:
>
> ```bash
> $ git diff master dev
> ```
>
> It will tell you that a function was added from the first file and a
> line was *added* to the README. Why? Because on the branch, the README
> still has the original line, but on ‘master’ you’ve removed it - so
> directly comparing the snapshots looks like ‘dev’ added it.
>
> What you really want to compare is what ‘dev’ has changed *since* your
> branches diverged. To do that, Git has a nice little shorthand:
>
> ```bash
> $ git diff master...dev
> ```

Comment: git diff foo...master
changes that master branch has introduced since it's common ancestor with foo

Comment: @manojlds ok, so different question, if you're at dev branch and commit your changes (the function) and push the changes into a remote dev branch does this mean the visible change is only the function or the function and the readme?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, GitHub's pull request diff uses the triple dot. Is that right?

Comment: Broken link to GitHub example page.

Comment: I never knew the 3 dot (`...`) version existed. I've always used `git diff $(git merge-base master dev) dev` instead of `git diff master...dev`, but they appear to be equivalent. So, for anyone wondering, apparently `git diff master...dev` is the same thing as `git diff $(git merge-base master dev) dev`.

Answer (score 6):

```bash
git diff foo master
```

will show the differences between the `foo` and `master` branch at that point in time

```bash
git diff foo..master
```

will also show the differences between the `foo` and `master` branches at that point in time (equivalent to the above).

```bash
git diff foo...master
```

will show all the differences between when the `foo` branch was made from the `master` branch and after.

So the first two commands are the same and last one shows a wider view of the diff history.

Answer (score 2):

[image: git log tree]

The top picture is equivalent to the bottom graph tree

```
A0 <- A1 <- A2 <- A3 (master)
   \
    C0 <- C1 (test)
```

A picture is worth a thousand words, the difference between `..` `...` `^` is shown below.

```
$ git log master..test
# output C0 C1

$ git log ^master test
# output C0 C1

$ git log master…test
# output A1 A2 A3 C0 C1
```