# How to see the commit messages that origin/master is ahead of master?

Tags: git

When git informs me that my local branch is behind master, how do I tell git to print out the log messages that I am behind on. For example, in the situation below how do I view the log messages of the 2 commits on origin/master that I don't have on master?

```
git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try (following "[Git diff `..` ? What's the difference between having `..` and no dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/git-diff-whats-the-difference-between-having-and-no-dots)"):

```
 git log master..origin/master
```

Which is the same as:

```
git log origin/master ^master
```

(show me the commits on `origin/master` which are *not* -- '`^`' -- on `master`)

[image: git log dots]

Comment: awesome answer, thanks, this is so much better than the man pages for git! thank you.

Comment: @ams: yes, it is all about commit range: http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-1.html#Commit-Ranges

Comment: @ams: it is also well explained in [the `gitrevisions` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html) (along with all other commit operators in git)