# git diff - show only what's new on the remote

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a local repo and a remote repo on github.  For business reasons, they aren't in sync.  I've done a lot of work on the local that I'm keeping, and now I'm manually adding whatever's new to the remote, to my local.  There are no branches.

When I use the command,

```
git diff --color master..origin/master
```

I get good results, showing what changed.... what I have added to the local repo is marked with a - sign, and is shown in red; while what is on the remote is shown in green with + signs.

Is there a way to show **only what is new on the remote** and not on the local?  That is, show me any new files on the remote and show me any new or modified lines in files on the remote (show me all the green +'s)

thanks.

Comment: is it as simple as:
`git diff --color master..origin/master | grep +`

Comment: Thanks for answering.  This does not work if there are +'s in the text of some files that are tracked.  Any other way?
P.S. I'm new to git and to terminal. :-)

Comment: that returned nothing...

Comment: Hey I figured out a way to help.  I had a few large files I knew I didn't want to see the diff of.  I created a .gitattributes file in my project directory and added 2 lines:
 *.xml -diff and *.txt -diff.  For me, this greatly reduced what I was having to page through to see differences.  Thanks.

Comment: `git diff master..origin/master | grep ^+`
I think this is what Carl mentioned.

Comment: Yes, the ^+ didn't return anything.  I don't know why.  However, the combination of removing xml and txt files from diff in .gitattributes AND using | grep + as you suggested works great.  Thanks! :-)  Why do you think ^+ didn't work for me?

Comment: Also how do I mark an accepted answer?  I don't see a checkmark.  I guess that's because the answers were put in as comments instead of answers. ?  (This is my first post.)

Comment: @Darby you can post an answer below, and select your own answer as the selected one.

Answer (score 12):

I believe you can put 3 dots between the two branches in the command and then it does only whats new in the second with respect to the first, i.e.

```
git diff master...feature
```

to see what's new on feature, and

```
git diff feature...master
```

to see what's new on master. In your case feature can be `origin/master` and that should work fine.

Comment: Right: three dots for `git diff`, vs. two dots for `git log`! http://stackoverflow.com/a/14426939/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6309

Answer (score 1):

You can diff with the common ancestor:

```
git diff `git merge-base master origin/master` origin/master
```

Or with your previous fetch:

```
git diff origin/master@{1} origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at `git help rev-list`.  The option you are probably looking for is `--right-only`, so maybe this gets you what you want:

```
git diff --color --right-only master..origin/master
```