# git rebase --onto fails

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I created a local repository for learning git so losing data is not a problem.

**Current tree:**

```
*   006f7ab - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'hotfix' idc what will heppen :( - stav alfi (master
|\
| * 0f028e8 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
* | fc040d3 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
* | ed29b30 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
|/
* a7c5bb3 - (2 days ago) good branch - stav alfi
* 9d804c2 - (2 days ago) new.txt changed in 16:35 - stav alfi
* 6ada3b7 - (2 days ago) new.txt changed in 16:32 - stav alfi (oldDad)
* f6497fc - (2 days ago) this is the nest commit! - stav alfi (oldDad1)
* b1b3e25 - (2 days ago) omg - stav alfi
* 74656b3 - (2 days ago) new1234 - stav alfi
* e8977d3 - (2 days ago) fast commit - stav alfi
* 114b46c - (3 days ago) good - Stav Alfi
* 8212c78 - (3 days ago) good - Stav Alfi
* 23dfc61 - (3 days ago) removed-something - Stav Alfi
* 184178d - (3 days ago) shortcut - Stav Alfi
* f1e606f - (3 days ago) good-commit - Stav Alfi
* 5ae787b - (3 days ago) initial-project-version1 - stav alfi
* 1321cba - (3 days ago) initial-project-version1 - stav alfi
* eae3e1c - (3 days ago) initial-project-version - stav alfi
* d3c3e93 - (3 days ago) initial-project-version - Stav Alfi
* db309e9 - (3 days ago) initial-project-version - Stav Alfi (HEAD -> newDad)
```

**Desired tree: (What I'm tring to do)**

```
*   006f7ab - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'hotfix' idc what will heppen :( - stav alfi (HEAD -> master)
|\
| * 0f028e8 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
* | fc040d3 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
* | ed29b30 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
|/
* a7c5bb3 - (2 days ago) good branch - stav alfi
* 9d804c2 - (2 days ago) new.txt changed in 16:35 - stav alfi
* 6ada3b7 - (2 days ago) new.txt changed in 16:32 - stav alfi (oldDad)
(....I want to remove all of this....)
* db309e9 - (3 days ago) initial-project-version - Stav Alfi (newDad)
```

**The command I used + error:**

```
$ git rebase --onto newDad oldDad1
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: new.txt changed in 16:32
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
A       new.txt
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
CONFLICT (modify/delete): new.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in new.txt changed in 16:32. Version new.txt changed in 16:32 of new.txt left in tree.
Patch failed at 0001 new.txt changed in 16:32
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

**git status (after running `git rebase --onto newDad oldDad1`)**

```
$ git status
rebase in progress; onto db309e9
You are currently rebasing branch 'master' on 'db309e9'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

        deleted by us:   new.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

**My questions:**

I'm failing to understand the error I got and what are to following words:
rewind,replay,applying.
I'm also don't know how to fix a conflict.

I'm interested to know what I did wrong and how to fix it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It isn't even clear if you did anything wrong.  Rebasing involves rewriting the history of a branch.  This happens by reapplying (i.e. recommitting) commits on top of a new base.  As such, merge conflicts can arise.  Please update your question by telling us what you are trying to do.

Comment: I wrote that under "Desired Tree"

Comment: Rebase onto is not what I think you want here.  You are asking for an interactive rebase which removes commits.  However, before an answer can be given, you should tell us whether this branch is publicly shared?  Or, is your branch only used by you and no one else?

Comment: Wrote that in start: I created a local repository for learning git so losing data is not a problem. Also please have a look in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29916361/806963 ; From that, rebase --onto can be used here too. But if you have a second way, I will love to learn also! Thanks!

Comment: What is your current commit (or branch name) when you first run `git rebase --onto newDad oldDad1`?  (It's clearly not `newDad` itself; I suspect it is `master`, i.e., commit `006f7ab`.) (This matters for explaining what you are getting. What you *want* to get is significantly harder.)

Comment: @torek Yes you are right. when I run that, HEAD = master  ,commit 006f7ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, deep breath :-)

#### Git's `rebase` *copies* commits

The fundamental trick that `git rebase` uses is the cherry-pick operation, which *copies* a commit.  We'll get to the mechanics of copying a commit at the moment, but consider a simple, ordinary `git cherry-pick`, where we `git checkout` some branch name—I will create a new one pointing to one particular commit here—and then tell Git to copy some other commit, typically one that is not (yet) on our new branch.

```
git checkout -b newbranch 23dfc61
```

This makes `23dfc61` the current commit but gives it a new branch *name*, `newbranch`.  Now we can make new commits, which add to the new branch, so now we run, e.g.:

```
git cherry-pick 9d804c2
```

to copy commit `9d8042c`.

The result, if this works—if there is no merge conflict, or after you clean up any merge conflict if there is one—is a new commit whose parent is `23dfc61`, and whose *source tree* is like `23dfc61` but with whatever you changed in `9d804c2` as compared to `6ada3b7`, added to it:

```
...
* 9d804c2 - (2 days ago) new.txt changed in 16:35 - stav alfi
* 6ada3b7 - (2 days ago) new.txt changed in 16:32 - stav alfi (oldDad)
* f6497fc - (2 days ago) this is the nest commit! - stav alfi (oldDad1)
* b1b3e25 - (2 days ago) omg - stav alfi
* 74656b3 - (2 days ago) new1234 - stav alfi
* e8977d3 - (2 days ago) fast commit - stav alfi
* 114b46c - (3 days ago) good - Stav Alfi
* 8212c78 - (3 days ago) good - Stav Alfi
| * NNNNNNN - (now) new.txt changed in 16:35 - stav alfi (HEAD -> newbranch)
|/
* 23dfc61 - (3 days ago) removed-something - Stav Alfi
* 184178d - (3 days ago) shortcut - Stav Alfi
...
```

We don't know what the new hash number will be, so I put in `NNNNNNN`.  But the new commit has the same *log message* as the old one, and *makes the same change* as the old one.

#### Commits contain snapshots, not changes

Each commit has, attached to it, the *complete source* as of the time of that commit.  This is different from many other version control systems: most tend to store each commit as a *change* from the commit before them, or the commit after them.  What this means here is that in order to *copy* a commit, Git first has to *find out* what changed.

The way to find out is to compare the commit to its *parent* commit.  The parent commit of `9d804c2` is `6ada3b7`, so Git does:

```
git diff 6ada3b7 9d804c2
```

to see what *changed*.  Assuming the log message is accurate, you changed something in `new.txt`, so that's what Git will find.  That, then, is *also* what Git will try to do when it tries to modify the snapshot saved for `23dfc61` to come up with a new snapshot for `NNNNNNN`.

If that succeeds, Git will commit the result, and will have made a successful cherry-pick.

#### No commit can *ever* be changed

The unpronounceable hash IDs `23dfc61` and `6ada3b7` and `badf00d` and `bedface` and so on are constructed by taking the exact contents of each commit.  If you try to *change* **anything** about any commit, Git builds a new commit; if there's even a single bit different anywhere, you get a new, different hash, so you get a new, different commit.

The parts that go into this include all the source, plus the parent ID, as each commit "points to" (contains the ID of) its parent.  (There are also some time stamps, so unless you make the same commit twice in the same second, you still get two different IDs, even if they have the rest of their bits identical.)  Hence, to change anything—whether it's the source, or just a parent ID—Git *must* copy commits.

This is why rebase copies commits: it *must*.  You are taking some set of commits, turning each one into a change, and then applying those changes starting at some *different* commit, which has a different parent ID, even if it has the same source tree.  So what you give to `git rebase` is, essentially, two chunks of information:

- Which commits should it copy?
- Where should it place those copies?

The place to copy is easy if you use `--onto`, as that's the place!  The set of commits to *copy*, however, is trickier.

#### Selecting commits

Git provide a *range* notation, `X..Y`, that looks like it means "commits between X and Y"—and it does, sort of.  But not quite!  In fact, Git uses something we call *reachability*, following parent links in commits.  We already noted that each commit has a parent ID stored in it.  That's how Git can find your commits: you tell it to start at a *branch tip*, using a *branch name* like `master`, and it finds that particular commit by its hash ID, which Git remembers for you inside the name `master`.

That commit has another hash ID in it: this is the commit's parent.  Git uses that hash ID to find *that* commit.  The parent has yet another hash ID, and Git keeps finding more and more parents.  This goes on as long as it possibly can, all the way back to the very first commit you ever made.

That's too many commits, so we tell Git to *stop* going back at some point.  That's the "Y" part of `X..Y`: this tells Git *start at Y and work backwards, marking commits "green" temporarily to take them*.  But, at the same time, *start at X and work backwards, marking commits "red" temporary to* avoid *taking them*.

I like to draw all of this with one-letter names for commits, instead of the big ugly hash IDs, and connecting lines that have older commits at the left and newer commits at the right:

```
...--D--E--F--G--H   <-- branch
```

Here commit `H` is the *tip* of the branch, `G` is `H`'s parent, `F` is `G`'s parent, and so on.  If we write `E..H`, that paints `E` (and `D` and on back) "red": stop, don't take these!  Then it paints `H` green, and then `G` and `F`, and then we hit the red-painted `E` and stop.  So that *selects* commits `F-G-H`.  `E` is naturally excluded here.

But when we have branches and merges, things get trickier:

```
          F--G--H
         /       \
...--D--E         K--L
         \       /
          I-----J
```

Commit `K` is a *merge* commit.  A merge commit is one that has two (or more, but let's not go there) parents.  If we stick with the red and green paint analogy, `E..L` means "paint `E` and on back red and paint `L` on back green": when we hit `K`, we paint *both* `H` *and* `J` green, and work back on *both sides* of this branch/merge.

If we say `G..L`, look how that works: we paint `G` red, then `F`, then `E` and `D` and so on.  We never paint `I` at all, because that's not *backwards* from `F`: we can only move *back*, not forward, during this process.  So then we paint `L` green, and `K`, and then both `H` and `J`. `G` is already red, so we stop *that* side, but keep going on the other, painting `I` green.  Then we move back to `E`, but it's red so we stop.  So *this* selects `I` and `J`, and also `H`, and `K` and `L` (in some order).

#### What `git rebase` copies: merges are a problem

When Git goes to select commits to *copy*, it uses your other (not-`--onto`) argument as the "red paint" part of the stop item, and your *current* commit as the "green paint" part.  If you don't use `--onto`, the onto target is the *same* as the red-paint selector.  That's all `--onto` does: it lets you choose a different "stop" red-paint selector than the target.

But if there is a merge in here—and in your case, there is—we have a problem, or really, *two* problems.  One is that rebase *cannot copy* a merge, so it just does not even try.  It just removes merges entirely, from the set of commits to copy.  The other is that we follow *both legs* of a branch-and-merge, but we do not get to control the *order* unless we use an interactive (`-i`) rebase.

You were on `master` and ran:

```
git rebase --onto newDad oldDad1
```

so this selects:

```
oldDad1..master
```

as the commits to copy, but throws out all the merges, and linearizes the remainder of the commits.  That means you start with:

```
*   006f7ab - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'hotfix' idc what will heppen :( - stav alfi (master
|\
| * 0f028e8 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
* | fc040d3 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
* | ed29b30 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
|/
* a7c5bb3 - (2 days ago) good branch - stav alfi
* 9d804c2 - (2 days ago) new.txt changed in 16:35 - stav alfi
* 6ada3b7 - (2 days ago) new.txt changed in 16:32 - stav alfi (oldDad)
```

but end up with:

```
* 0f028e8 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
* fc040d3 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
* ed29b30 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
* a7c5bb3 - (2 days ago) good branch - stav alfi
* 9d804c2 - (2 days ago) new.txt changed in 16:35 - stav alfi
* 6ada3b7 - (2 days ago) new.txt changed in 16:32 - stav alfi (oldDad)
```

or—since we don't control the order:

```
* fc040d3 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
* ed29b30 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
* 0f028e8 - (2 days ago) good - stav alfi
* a7c5bb3 - (2 days ago) good branch - stav alfi
* 9d804c2 - (2 days ago) new.txt changed in 16:35 - stav alfi
* 6ada3b7 - (2 days ago) new.txt changed in 16:32 - stav alfi (oldDad)
```

(all I did here was swap the two legs around).  Git will check out commit  `db309e9` (newDad, your `--onto`) as a temporary branch, and then start cherry-picking each commit, turning `6ada3b7` into a change by comparing it against `f6497fc`.  But this immediately fails:

> ```
> error: Failed to merge in the changes.
> Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
> A       new.txt
> Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
> CONFLICT (modify/delete): new.txt deleted in HEAD and modified 
>  in new.txt changed in 16:32. Version new.txt changed in 16:32
>  of new.txt left in tree.
> ```

The problem here is that `new.txt` *does not exist* in commit `db309e9`.  Git does not know how to combine "make a slight change to `new.txt`" with "don't have a `new.txt` at all".

It's now your job to fix this conflict, by deciding how to have `new.txt` appear in the final snapshot.  Edit or remove the file in the work-tree and when you are done, `git add` the result and run `git rebase --continue` and Git will go on to attempt to cherry-pick the next commit.

This repeats until `git rebase` has copied all the to-be-copied commits.  Once that finishes, `git rebase` tells Git to "peel off" the original branch label (`master`) and paste it onto the last commit it just made.  So now the `master` branch will name the newest commit, which will point back to its parent, and so on.  The original commits—the ones you copied—are still in the repository, for a while, but they are now "abandoned" from this branch: they do not have the name `master` available to find them.

#### But existing branch names can still find the existing commits

The names `oldDad` and `oldDad1` still point to some of the original (not-copied) commits here.  Those names will still find those original commits.  If there were more names that remembered some of the *copied* commits, those names would still remember the originals too.  So the copied commits are not only not gone, sometimes they are still visible, depending on branch names.

#### Note that your final merge is just gone

Because `git rebase` does not even *try* to copy the merge, your merge commit will simply be omitted entirely.  However, since both "legs" of the merge get applied (in some order), the final *source tree* will match, provided you resolve any conflicts appropriately.  How hard or easy that will be depends on which leg gets done first and whether the two legs affect each other.

#### There *is* a `--preserve-merges` flag

There *is* a way to get `git rebase` to attempt to preserve merges.  But it cannot *actually* preserve them.  Instead, what it does is to copy each leg of a fork as before, but this time, by forking the two legs; and then when it reaches the merge commit, it runs a *new* `git merge` to make a *new* merge that—Git hopes—is "just as good" as the original.

In this particular case, `--preserve-merges` won't help with the immediate problem, because that happens before the branch-and-re-merge sequence.  This `new.txt` file that is modified in the first commit you are cherry-picking, but does not exist in your starting-point, happens well before the branch-and-merge sequence.  Whether `--preserve-merges` is any use to you, I do not know.

Comment: Thank you! You explained a lot of things that were not clear  and that was exactly what I looked for. One question: Under 'What git rebase copies: merges are a problem', what you explained what will be pained as green after I run `git rebase --onto newDad oldDad1` , you didn't say anything about the top most commit, `006f7ab - (2 days ago) Merge branch 'hotfix' ...`. Why isn't this commit painted to green also? Thanks again!!

Comment: That's covered under "merges are a problem". Without --preserve-merges, rebase simply drops them entirely, linearizing both legs. See the rest above.