# Git - Revert merge with history of one branch

Tags: git, merge, revert

I have the great job to clean up a fu**ed up git repository. In the past someone merged the whole linux kernel src into the repository (with all the 650k commits). I know the commit id from the merge and also from the parent. Of course there were changes in the time between merging linux with the masterbranch, so at the moment the tree looks similar to this

```
-x-x-x-x-LinuxMerge-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-today
```

What I want is to revert the LinuxMerge commit incl. the history of this. Is this possibly and how?

Answer (score 2):

I think some confusion is raised with this question, because you phrase it as wanting to "revert" the mistake - and "revert" means something specific to git.  I know what you mean isn't what git means by that word, because with git's meaning a phrase like "revert history" isn't a thing.

Because you want to undo the change entirely, a history rewrite is the first step.  AnoE's answer shows one way to do this, assuming that there is just one ref from which the bad merge is reachable, and that there are no merge commits "between" that ref and the bad merge.

In the event there are multiple refs, you'd need to do something more.  For example if you had

```
x -- x -- x --- ML -- x -- A -- x <--(master)
               /            \
(linux history)              o <--(branch_one)
```

completing the rebase would give you

```
            x' -- A' -- x' <--(master)
           /
x -- x -- x --- ML -- x -- A -- o <--(branch_one)
               /
(linux history)
```

You'd then need to transplant the `o` commit, with something like

```
git rebase --onto A' A branch_one
```

(replacing `A` and `A'` with either the commit ID or some other expression that names the appropriate commit).

If there are merges that need to be rewritten, then you have a bigger issue.  The `rebase` command will try to write a linear history by default.  You can tell it you want to keep the merge topology with the `--preserve-merges` option, but it may not work properly.  If a merge commit had conflicts, you'll have to re-resolve it.  Worse, if a merge commit *doesn't* have conflicts, but was not originally completed using the default merge result, then `rebase` will not recreate the merge (or any children of it) correctly.

So the only safe way to rebase, then, is in segments, manually reproducing merges as you encounter them.

Another option might be to use `git filter-branch` instead of `rebase`; but this is tricky, too.  It's only workable if you can script the removal of anything the merge introduced.  For example, if the linux history is in different paths than your own work, so that you could clean up a given instance of the content by `rm`ing certain paths, then you could use `filter-branch`.

(Since this is an option that may or may not be viable for you, for now I won't spell out the detailed steps.  The `filter-branch` documentation can fill in the blanks.  Basically you'd use a `parent-filter` to bypass the merge commit (by re-parenting the following commit onto the first parent commit), plus an `index-filter` or `tree-filter` to remove the linux files from the subsequent commits.)

One way or another, once you have the history cleaned up you would *still* have all that history in your repo's database.  At a minimum you need to make sure nothing references that history.  Then it would eventually get cleared out by `gc` (or you could force that to happen sooner).

Mostly that means you have to find any refs that can reach the linux history.  Since the rewrite moved "your" refs, this would likely comprise any refs (branches or tags) pulled in with the linux history itself.  So you'd just want to delete those.

There also will be reflogs that can (indirectly) reach the linux history, and gc can't remove history that's reachable in this way.  Honestly at this point the easiest thing to do is probably to re-clone the repo (as a new clone *should* only get the current refs and their history) and replace origin with the result.

If you want to repair an existing repo instead of re-cloning for whatever reason, the next step would be to wipe out reflogs (I usually just `rm -r .git/logs`) and then run an aggressive `gc` (see the `gc` docs)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see, its hard to solve such an issue... But thanks for this informations!

Answer (score 1):

You can undo this by rebasing.

If you start out from this...

```
-x-x-x-x-LinuxMerge-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-today
```

... then you probably are talking about that, instead:

```
-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-today
        /
-linus-/
```

Let's label some more commits:

```
-x-x-x-prev-merg-post-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-today
             /
     -linus-/
```

So, you want to glue `prev` and `post` together, and throw away `merg`. The command for this is:

```
git rebase merg today --onto prev
```

(Note that in the command, we mention `merg`, not `post`; this is the typical "+-1" issue with declaring commit ranges in `git`).

This rebase command will add a new line of commits and change the `today` branch to point at the new tail:

```
          post'-y-y-y-y-y-y-y-today'
         /
-x-x-x-prev-merg-post-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-today
             /
     -linus-/
```

And if you just ignore the older stuff, this flattens out to:

```
-x-x-x-prev-post'-y-y-y-y-y-y-y-today'
```

The rebase will also change the `today` branch to point at the commit labeled `today'` in this ASCII picture.

Note that `post'` and the `y` commits (as well as `today'`) will all have different hashes than the originals, they are not the "same" commits.

If no other tags or branches point to the history leading up to `linus`, then those commits and related objects will be purged eventually by the git garbage collection (which you could force with `git gc` to make sure).

Comment: This still doesn't clean up the database, though - which is a bit ironic since you called Enrico's answer out for the same thing.  At best this procedure *might* make the history eventually become eligible for gc, assuming no refs were brought in with the linux history, and that origin runs in a context where `gc` happens from time to time

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, @MarkAdelsberger, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see, its hard to solve such an issue... But thanks for this informations!

Comment: @alabamajack: no, it's not that hard, really - the explanation just was a bit long. :) In practice, it's just a single "rebase" command (provided everything goes well...).

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here.

#### Option 1: Rewriting history

If you are able to *rewrite* the history of the `master` branch without consequences, the quickest way to achieve what you want is to simply *remove* the merge commit altogether with `git rebase --onto`:

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto <SHA-1-of-the-linux-merge>^ <SHA-1-of-the-linux-merge>
```

This means: "*rebase `master` on top of the first parent of the merge commit starting from the merge commit itself*". This will effectively remove the merge commit and apply all subsequent commits on top of its first parent. You can read more about how `git rebase --onto` works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29916361/26396).

#### Option 2: Reverting the merge

If you want to avoid rewriting history, you can always revert the "LinuxMerge" commit by using `git-revert`:

```
git revert --mainline-parent 1 --no-commit <SHA-1-of-the-linux-merge>
```

The [`--mainline-parent`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#git-revert---mainlineparent-number) option tells Git which parent of the merge commit you want to revert *to*. In this case, you want to revert to the *first* parent, that is the commit where the Linux kernel was merged *to*.

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#git-revert---mainlineparent-number):

> Usually you cannot revert a merge because you do not know which side of the merge should be considered the mainline. This option specifies the parent number (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows revert to reverse the change relative to the specified parent.

Note that reverting a merge this way will cause later merges of the same branch to *exclude* the commits that were originally brought in by the reverted merge:

> Reverting a merge commit declares that you will never want the tree changes brought in by the merge. As a result, later merges will only bring in tree changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors of the previously reverted merge. This may or may not be what you want.

However, in this case it sounds like you won't be merging the Linux kernel again anytime soon.

As for the [`--no-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#git-revert---no-commit) option, it lets you do a *dry run* to see whether you get any conflicts in your working directory without actually creating the commit.

Comment: I know this, but I thought I am false. I did it and get
`error [...] hint: after resolving mark corrected paths [...]`
git status shows :
`You are currently reverting commit 1234567 .
(fix conflicts and run "git revert --continue") [...] Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

   added by us:     file.sh`
after `git add file.sh` I get 
`git status: (all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")`
but doing this always says `You are currently reverting commit 1234567.
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: Did you include the `-m 1` option? The error message you got tells you that some changes made _before_ the merge conflict with changes made _afterwards_. At this point, you need to [resolve the conflicts](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/) in order to proceed with the revert.

Comment: If you run `git revert` with the `--no-commit` option, you can simply commit the changes with `git commit` after you resolved the conflicts.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Yes, `git revert` will undo the change, but simply by adding a new commit that "inverts" all file changes. They still will have 650K commits sitting in the history, with hundreds of megabytes of history.

Comment: Reverting a commit will cause so many issues. I personally would avoid it.

Comment: Yes I added `-m 1`. The curious thing is, that `git status` says, that all conflicts are fixed. If I run `git revert --continue` afterwards, I get `You are currently reverting commit 1234567.
nothing to commit, working directory clean`. I don't get the problem.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5227053/ano , is there a way to solve what I want?

Comment: @alabamajack I just noticed that you said "_including the history_". I updated my answer with a better approach.