# Rebased dev branch on master, master got reverted few commits back. Is it safe to do a rebase on reverted master again?

Tags: git, version-control

First of, I rebased on master:

```
A - B - C
         \
          D' - E'
```

Then, the master got reverted few commits back, so remotely it looks like:

```
A - B
```

While locally, my dev branch still has the `C` commits. Is it safe to do a

`git pull origin master
git rebase master`

Won't some of the commits duplicate? What is the proper way to get back to

```
A - B
      \
       D' - E'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve the desired history is to use

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

and drop the unwanted commits (`C`) from the list.

The answer to "is it safe?" is "yes, if done right".

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to the problem**

There is a simple solution using --onto

```
git rebase --onto B C
```

this mean :

> Rebase the commit reachable from HEAD whose parent is C on top of B.

- if you want to understand clearly what rebase --onto do, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/29916361/9936783
- or more generaly if you want to better understanding rebasing: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

**Safety of the propose solution**

In your case,

```
    master
        |
A - B - C
         \ 
          D' - E'
               |
              HEAD
```

`git pull origin master`

```
 master
    |
A - B - C
         \ 
          D' - E'
               |
              HEAD
```

`git rebase master`

will just do nothing. As you can see your HEAD is already base on master. So git will tell you there is nothing to do.

*In git, everything local (no push) is safe since you have no unversionned local modification, just put some temp tag or branches if you are not sure of what you do. You can always come back to these if you mess up your tree.*