# Rebase branch without parent branch

Tags: git

Firstly, I imagine this is duplicate; I'm guessing there's a name for what I'm trying to do, but I can't find anything about it.

Imagine I have commits:

```
a1 -- a2 -- b1 -- b2 -- c1 -- c2
```

Where `a`, `b`, and `c` are branches. I'm trying to get the history so that it is:

```
     - b1 -- b2
   /
a1 -- a2 -- c1 -- c2
```

But if I try and rebase `c` onto `a`, I understandably get `b` as well.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Maybe the duplicate would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914052/i-cant-understand-the-behaviour-of-git-rebase-onto.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't understand the behaviour of git rebase --onto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914052/i-cant-understand-the-behaviour-of-git-rebase-onto)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are multiple steps. The basic operation is `git rebase --onto <newbase> <oldbase> <tip>` (where `newbase` and `oldbase` can be commit hashes or branch names, but `tip` should be a branch name).

I'm assuming you have branches `b` and `c` pointing to commits `b2` and `c2`, respectively.

1. `git rebase --onto a2 b2 c`

   Result:

   ```
             - b1 -- b2
           /
   a1 -- a2 -- c1 -- c2
   ```

   Note that `b1` and `b2` are still unchanged, I just had to move them up visually.
2. `git rebase --onto a1 a2 b`

   Result:

   ```
       - b1 -- b2
     /
   a1 -- a2 -- c1 -- c2
   ```