# Rebasing commits that are identical in content, but different in hash

Tags: git, rebase

In a project I work on there's a weird system in which I can essentially feed in new commits to be appended to master. Instead of commiting the patches as they are put in, they're slightly modified in its metadata (the content is 100% identical though). Unfortunately, this means that my local commit IDs do not match up with the remote once they've gone through the system. I.e., imagine I have a local copy of the remote repository with three commits:

`C1 -> C2 -> C3`

Now I locally create three new commits locally, `X4` to `X6`

`C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> X4 -> X5 -> X6`

I then submit `X4` into the system, which is changed into `C4` (content identical, hash different). That means the remote now has

`C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4`

and my local one

`C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> X4 -> X5 -> X6`

I would want to pull from the remote `C4`, drop my local `X4` and append `X5` to `C4, so that I locally get:

`C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> X5 -> X6`

Right now I'm doing this by locally running `git format-patch`, then `git reset --hard origin/master` and `git pull`, then `git am` with only `X5` and `X6`. It's an annoying and tedious process, is there a better way?

Comment: I have updated the answer to remove the optional step

Comment: Note that if the diff from C3 to C4 matches the diff from C3 to X4, `git rebase` will omit C4 on its own. If it's *not* doing that, the snapshot in X4 must differ from that in C4, enough so that the two `git diff`s produce different `git patch-id`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Repo

```
C1---C2---C3---X4---X5---X6 (master)
```

Remote Repo

```
C1---C2---C3---C4 (origin/master)
```

**Fetch the changes from remote** *(origin)*

```
git fetch origin
```

Local Repo

```
C1---C2---C3---X4---X5---X6 (master)
           \
            C4 (origin/master)
```

**Rebase current branch** *(master)* **onto C4 and leave out X4**

```
git rebase --onto C4 X4
```

Local Repo

```
C1---C2---C3---C4---X5---X6 (master)
                \
                 (origin/master)
```

[More info on rebase onto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29916361/10155936)

Answer (score 0):

An interactive rebase may do the trick.

You should be able to do a `git pull --rebase=i`
In the interactive UI, to discard your X4 commit replace "pick" by "drop" or "d".

rebase doc : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing