# Rebase onto a new branch to remove unpushed commit on wrong branch

Tags: git, github

I accidentally committed to a branch that I didn't realize someone else was working on and my changes are completely incompatible with what they have done. By total coincidence, our branch names just happened to be the same.

I haven't pushed to their branch, but I did commit locally.

I tried doing `git rebase --onto some-branch-alt some-branch` but I get the error:

```
fatal: Does not point to a valid commit 'some-branch-alt'
```

How do I move my commits on `some-branch` over to a new separate branch `some-branch-alt` which itself is branched from somewhere completely different from the other author's git branch?

Comment: Related, possibly even a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29914052/184546
Presumably, some part of your syntax is incorrect.

Comment: I assume you already created a branch called some-branch-alt? Then try changing the last word from some-branch to some-branch~x where x is the number of commits you added to some-branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the commit is the last one on `some-branch`, to transfer the commit you simply do:

```
git checkout some-branch-alt
git cherry-pick some-branch
```

To remove the commit from the old branch, you just redefine it to point to the previous commit:

```
git branch -f some-branch some-branch~
```

Comment: After creating the new branch you can also just delete some-branch since there's probably no reason to have a local copy of it.

Comment: Looks like commits is plural.