# How to update my feature branch after a force push on the base branch . We only use rebase, merges are forbidden

Tags: git, rebase, git-push, git-history, git-history-rewrite

We are working with a very simple structure in git.

First we have our `master` branch.

Below we have `develop`

And finally we can have any `feature` branch

We only use rebase for updating the history on our branches and then f-forwarding to the above branch.

Weekly, we have our `develop` branch that has been updated with some `features`. And this branch is  rebased and merged into master (from `develop` to `master`).

**THE PROBLEM**

When we are rebasing and merging `develop` to `master` , sometimes there are conflicts and I have to fix them by performing a `master` rebase into my `develop` branch. After fixing conflicts I perform a `git push --force-with-lease` to upload changes to remote.

After this procedure, the history of develop has being changed because of the force push.

The problem resides when another developer was working on a `feature` branch based on `develop` but, the one before the force push (`develop` before the force push).

How can we update the `feature` branch of this developer with the new history of `develop` branch.
Because, when doing a `git rebase develop`  inside our `feature` branch. We end up with a lot of conflicts.

Comment: Are merges completely forbidden? Sounds like all you would have to do is to ask that developer to merge `develop` into his `feature` branch and resolve conflicts in there. After, it should be good to merge into `develop`

Comment: You probably need [`git rebase --onto <newparent> <oldparent>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29916361/7987488), where `<newparent>` is `develop` branch, and `<oldparent>` is the parent of a very first commit in the `feature` branch.

Comment: Do developers typically ff merge into `develop` and rarely into `master`? Or is it common for them to ff merge into `master` sometimes too? (i.e. What is the reason `master` sometimes diverges from `develop`?)

Comment: I think the problem is that develop is not your base. Develop is an integration branch and it is disposable. `Master` is your true base/trunk branch. Please see my detailed answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Another way to clean up the developer's feature branch is to create a new feature branch from master, and cherry-pick the developer's commits from the old feature branch into the new feature branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the developper was is this situation :

```
--*--x--*--m <- master
      \
       \
        *--*--f <- develop
               \
                a--b--c <- feature
```

and after he fetches the update, he reaches :

```
--*--x--*--m <- master
      \     \
       \     *--*--f' <- develop
        *--*--f
               \
                a--b--c <- feature
```

---

To only replay `a, b, c` on top of `develop`, apply the command suggested by @Vitali :

- spot commit `f` : the original fork point between `feature` and `develop`,
- run : `git rebase --onto develop <f> feature`

If all goes well, he will reach the following state :

```
--*--x--*--m <- master
            \
             *--*--f' <- develop
                    \
                     a'--b'--c' <- feature

# only 'a--b--c' are replayed from the original 'feature' branch,
# not '*--*--f'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's straightforward with interactive rebase or git cherry-pick.

I think the interactive rebase is a bit faster. See the section titled [Changing Multiple Commit Messages](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) in the git-scm documentation for more details.

**Interactive Rebase in Two Steps**

1. Create `my-feature-cleanup` branch. Omit all of the old work by starting from the `master` branch.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b my-feature-cleanup
```

2. Issue the interactve rebase command to rebase the good commits from `my-feature` into the `my-feature-cleanup` branch.

```
git rebase -i origin/my-feature
```

The above command should open a git-rebase-todo editor window. Choose `pick` for the commit that you want to keep and `drop` for the commits that you don't want to keep.

```
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
```

**Another option**

Cherry pick will also work. It's the same idea but may require multiple commands to [cherry pick individual commits](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) instead of doing it all at once.

1. It starts out the same way

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b my-feature-cleanup
```

2. List the commits in my-feature

```
git log my-feature
commit 02345 Something I did
commit 12345 Merge branch 'X' of 'Y'
commit 22345 A thing someone else did
commit 32345 Another thing I did
```

3. Cherry pick individual commits from my-feature beginning with the oldest one

```
git cherry-pick 32345
git cherry-pick 02345
```

This will put two commits on my-feature-cleanup.

```
git log my-feature-cleanup
02345 Something I did
32345 Another thing I did
etc...
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is `git rebase --onto` which you can find in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914052/how-to-git-rebase-a-branch-with-the-onto-command).
Another kind of long way is:

1.

```
git checkout -b feature1 develop  # this will create a new branch that will be in sync with your current develop
```

2. Check the commits on your `feature` branch and take note of the start and last commit over `develop`.
3. 

```
git cherry-pick <commitA>^..<commitB>
```

4. Conflicts would always be there for you to resolve but I find it less prone to introducing errors. Resolve them.
5. Once you are satisfied with the current branch, delete the old `feature` branch and rename `feature1` to `feature`.

Answer (score 0):

---

**THE PROBLEM** : Commits from a deleted integration branch exist in a feature branch. They need to be deleted or reverted.

**DETAILED SOLUTION**:
In the future, change your workflow as follows.

- **Do not** merge the integration branch into a feature branch. `git pull origin develop`
- **Do** merge master into a feature branch. `git pull origin master`
- **Do** merge a feature branch into the integration branch named develop. `git checkout develop && git merge my-feature`

---

**Details**

The ff-only option ensures devs only get changes that are fast-forwardable **and** that their feature doesn't get polluted by transient mutations in the develop branch.

Developers should originate their `feature-that-works` branch from `master`.

At the start of work:

```
git pull
git checkout master
git checkout -b feature-that-works
```

Now I have a new branch named `feature-that-works` and I am ready to start coding my feature.

What happens if I pull the integration branch `develop` directly into my `feature-that-works` branch? My feature branch gets contaminated with every other work-in-progress that's merged into the integration branch. I don't have control of other work in progress and generally, I don't want it contaminating my clean feature branch. That is why I do not pull from the integration branch named `develop` into my `feature-that-works`.

**Stay up to date with changes**

It's not a problem to pull master into a feature branch. Sometimes I fetch from master several times per day in my continuous deployment project. This is fine!

```
git checkout feature-that-works
git pull --ff-only origin master
```

The command above with the --ff-only option *will fail* if there  are conflicts.

**What to do when there are conflicts**

This next command rebases master under feature-that-works.

`git pull -r origin master`

When the `ff-only` option fails due to conflicts, I must rebase my branch *on top* of master. Another way to say this is that I need to rebase master *under* my feature branch. This ensures that the master branch can always be fast-forwarded.

By rebasing in my local feature branch it will be possible to replay the commit history from my feature branch onto the master branch without any merge conflicts. I am resolving all conflicts locally, rather than waiting until it's time to apply my changes onto the master branch. If there's a problem, hopefully it's a small one that I can resolve locally, instead of waiting and making it someone else's bigger headache downstream.

Here's [another good explanation](https://blog.sffc.xyz/post/185195398930/why-you-should-use-git-pull-ff-only-git-is-a) with a simple visual describing why `ff-only` is preferred to git merge.

An interesting fact: without the `ff-only` option the `git pull` command is actually the same as `git fetch` + `git merge`.

**Integration**

I merge a `feature-that-works` into `develop`. As I mentioned before, it does **not** work the other way around.

```
git push origin feature-that-works
git fetch
git checkout develop
git reset --hard origin/develop
git pull origin feature-that-works
git push origin develop
```

The reason I used `git reset --hard origin/develop` is because the develop branch is mutable. Develop can be force pushed by someone else. I want to make sure that my local develop branch matches the remote upstream branch origin/develop.

That's just about it. Keep in mind that even with good workflow, developers need to communicate and may occasionally have to resolve merge conflicts together with other devs.