# Why I'm getting conflicts when I merge the 3rd level branch to master after merging the 2 second level

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I always have an issue when I got this scenario in my work

```
0 <- 1 <- 2 <----------- 9 <--- master
           \            /
            3 <- 4 <- 5 <------ Feature/A
                       \
                        6 <- 7 <- 8   <-- HEAD=Feature/B
```

so we have a master, we created new **feature/A** from master
and later we created another feature **feature/B** from feature/A

now **Feature/A** got merged to master at **5**

we need to merge **Feature/B** to master too, but we are getting tons of conflicts for no reason.

any idea what is causing that please , and how I can avoid this?

**Edit**

To  merge B into master I run

```
git merge master
```

from `Feature B` I ran `git merge-base --all HEAD master` and the result was 2

which is **releae/1.14.1**  as you can see it in more detail on the next graph

my graph log command :

`git log --graph --oneline master feature/member feature/fund-test`

as feature/member is Feature A

feature/fund-test is Feature B

releae/1.14.1 Is where feature/A started which is 2

7640e46aa IS 9

```
|\
| * c354b9142 update claims upon registering.
|/
*   7640e46aa Merge branch 'feature/members' into 'master'
|\
| * 43ea27cb2 Feature/Members
|/
| *   ef276ed89 (HEAD -> fund-test, origin/fund-test) Merge branch 'minor-changes-fundraising-v3.1' into 'feature/fundraising-3.1'
| |\
| | * 952cfe3a9 (origin/add-missing-changes) Add changes resolve by git.
| |/
| * e924e1fc3 fixed changelog
| *   1d6eadffe Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/feature/members' into feature/fundraising-3.1
| |\
| | * 76d3f1aa4 (origin/feature/members, feature/members) Update data service comments
| | * 5b8cdf931 Update NuGet packages
| | *   cf978c86b Merge branch 'master' into feature/members
| | |\
| |_|/
|/| |
* | |   2754d5127 Merge branch 'releae/1.14.1' into 'master'
|\ \ \
| * | | d67a38076 Update changelogs
|/ / /
| | *   aa16154e4 Merge branch 'remove/context' into 'feature/members'
```

Comment: *tons of conflicts for no reason."* Well without knowing what exactly you've done here this question can't be answered. There **will** be a reason. But that very much depends on what you've done in the files in these branches

Comment: I assume 9 is a merge commit? Just to be clear, the feature A branch wasn't squashed when it was merged, or rebased? Both of those would cause lots of fun conflicts.

Comment: are you merging master first to featureB ? Also, what is the point to create featureB from featureA ? By looking at your diagram it is better to start featureB from master <commit9>

Comment: @Dmitry , some time you have two feature depending on each other, you can't start B from master as feature A can have a stuff that gonna be used in feature B

Comment: @SpoonMeiser 9 is merge commit yes , feature A has only push and merge into master at the end , nothing else . for some reason when I merge B to master it compare ,2 ,8 and 9 , and [2] will be the base on ( 3 way merge )

Comment: Can you let us know what commands you ran? If feature A has been merged into master, then 2 shouldn't be part of a 3-way merge

Comment: I run "git merge master"

Comment: I updated the question with more details , thanks a lot guys for the help anyway :D

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914052/how-to-git-rebase-a-branch-with-the-onto-command/29916361#29916361

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: given the note that hash ID `7640e46aa` is the commit you drew as `9`, we look at the two parents of `7640e46aa`.  They are:

```
43ea27cb2 Feature/Members
```

(this is the *second* parent, as `git log --graph` always draws that one to the right) and:

```
2754d5127 Merge branch 'releae/1.14.1' into 'master'
```

(this is the *first* parent, directly below the commit you called `2`).  So the top row of your graph is correct.  However, commit `43ea27cb2 Feature/Members` *does not* correspond to the commit you called `5`: it is an independent commit with `2754d5127` as its (single) parent.  That is, rather than:

> ```
> 0 <- 1 <- 2 <----------- 9 <--- master
>            \            /
>             3 <- 4 <- 5 <------ Feature/A
>                        \
>                         6 <- 7 <- 8   <-- HEAD=Feature/B
> ```

what we have looks like this:

```
0--1--2------------9   <-- master
       \___       /
        \  `---345   <-- Feature/Members
         \
          3--4--5   <-- Feature/A
                 \
                  6--7--8   <-- Feature/B
```

where commit `345` is the result of running `git checkout -b Feature/Members <hash-of-2> && git merge --squash Feature/A` rather than `git checkout master && git merge Feature/A`.  The squashed-together `345` was then merged with a regular merge into `master`, and the branch name `Feature/Members` (note upper case) deleted.  This branch was thus not related to the `feature/members` (note lower case) branch and commits `3`, `4`, and `5` conflict with commit `345`.

Your primary set of choices now lie between merging anyway (use a real merge if at all possible!) and resolving the conflicts, or use `git rebase --onto` to copy commits `6-7-8` to three new commits.  The advantage to using rebase is that the job will be easier.  The disadvantage is that the three replacement commits for `6-7-8` must be used as replacements in *every clone* that currently has those three commits.

(original answer below the line)

---

Assuming your drawing is accurate, the merge base of commits `8` and `9` is `5`.   To verify this, run:

```
git merge-base --all HEAD master
```

This should print just that one commit's hash ID.

Conflicts will arise if/when changes that show up in the diff from `5` to `8` overlap or abut with changes that show up in the diff from `5` to `9`.  That is, having obtained the merge base's hash ID (singular), run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-5> feature/B > /tmp/ours
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-5> master > /tmp/theirs
```

Compare the diff listings to see where conflicts might occur.

Since the merge at `9` was supposedly made *by* `git checkout master && git merge --no-ff feature/A`, and there *are no commits* between `9` and its first parent `2`, the changes that show up here, from `5` to `9`, should be exactly those changes that were made along the `3-4-5` path.  This means the diff from `5` to `9`, in `/tmp/theirs`, should be *empty*.  An empty diff cannot produce conflicts (with a non-empty *or* empty diff), so that either of:

```
git checkout master && git merge feature/B
```

or:

```
git checkout feature/B && git merge master
```

*should* have no conflicts.  Therefore I conclude that at least one assumption here is wrong.  The most likely one to be wrong is the assumption that your simplified commit graph drawing is correct.  Consider editing your question to include the output of `git log --graph --oneline master feature/A feature/B` (possibly with some of the commit message subject lines edited out, if necessary).  However, another possibility is that the simplified graph drawing *is* correct, but the merge at `9` is an evil merge: see [Evil merges in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452)  In this case the `/tmp/theirs` diff will be non-empty.

(My own guess is that commit `9` is a *squash merge*, and has no link back to commit `5`, so that the merge base is actually commit `2`.)

Comment: thanks a lot @torek for all this, I did update my question with the command you asked, I deleted some of stuff that I think it's not needed from the output as we have lots of commits there . I hope I didn't delete anything useful ,

Comment: we are using GitLab for merge , it squash the commits and merge => then it will make 9

Comment: @Aiman, then you need to rebase featureB onto master. The actual command to avoid conflicts will be `git rebase --onto`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914052/how-to-git-rebase-a-branch-with-the-onto-command/29916361#29916361

Comment: the problem on the rebase you have to resolve the conflicts commit by commit , if you have hundreds of commits that will be nightmare

Comment: my problem is I can't see why we are getting conflicts as B has everything in 5  and 5 got merged , so I should assume 0 conflicts