# Removes changes from another branch GIT

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-revert

I have created a branch from mybranch-1 instead of develop and then made a lot of commits on that new branch. Is there a way to remove the commits/changes made on mybranch-1 without removing the commits/changes made on my new branch ?

Comment: So `mybranch-1` is the name of that new branch. And you'd like to remove the commits/changes made on mybranch-1 _without_ removing the commits/changes made on the new branch? - I'm confused

Comment: Yes sorry for the bad explanation. mybranch-1 is not my new branch, it is another branch that I was working on and has its own commits. I have created mynewbranch from mybranch-1 by mistake (I wanted to create it from my develop branch) so now I want to remove to remove mybranch-1 commits from mynewbranch if it is possible ? Is it enough clear ? Sorry I'm not good at GIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your local branches looks like it:

```
   A---B---C---F---G (dev)        
            \
             D---E (mybranch-1)
                  \
                   H---I (newbranch)

  And you want to achieve:

   A---B---C---F---G (dev)        
                    \
                     H---I (newbranch)
```

The command you are looking for is `git rebase --onto`

For your case it will be `git rebase --onto dev mybranch-1 newbranch`

You can read more about said command on: [How to git rebase a branch with the onto command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914052/how-to-git-rebase-a-branch-with-the-onto-command)

Small note: The said command will remove commits that are on `mybranch-1` from `newbranch`, and will `rebase` `newbranch` with `dev` branch.