# I have created a feature branch from wrong branch and did my work on this branch

Tags: git, github, repository, git-rebase

example like : master A --> my branch B, --> correct branch C
I had to create B from C but accidentally created from A. and B branch has some of my commits as well.
I want to move B to the C branch with all commits. Pls Help.

```
           A ----> B
             \ --> C
```

It should be like this:

```
           A
             \ --> C ----> B
```

Comment: `git rebase C B`

Comment: i have already tried this approach but its showing fatal : invalid upstream 'C'

Comment: According to your graph, your brach/commit is called `C`. Since I cannot know your real branch name, I can only use the names given in your question.

Answer (score 1):

While branch B is checked out,

```
git rebase C
```

Other circumstances are described in detail at [How to git rebase a branch with the onto command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29914052/1549818)