# Gathering git commit information b/n 2 commits

Tags: git

I'm looking to gather commit information between 2 git commits and I used the below command

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%cn committed %h on %cd description %B files" --name-only 8ce980e ^99214db
```

and the output is below

```
DevTools App User committed 8ce980e on Mon Jun 6 09:09:28 2016 -0400 description Released Build version ${env.MAJOR_VERSION}.${env.MINOR_VERSION}.102
 files
.properties/release.properties

DevTools App User committed 179a8d9 on Mon Jun 6 08:12:40 2016 -0400 description Released Build version ${env.MAJOR_VERSION}.${env.MINOR_VERSION}.101
 files
.properties/release.properties

DevTools App User committed 2dc3410 on Mon Jun 6 07:48:21 2016 -0400 description Released Build version ${env.MAJOR_VERSION}.${env.MINOR_VERSION}.100
 files
.properties/release.properties

DevTools App User committed 49b34c7 on Mon Jun 6 06:23:30 2016 -0400 description Released Build version ${env.MAJOR_VERSION}.${env.MINOR_VERSION}.99
 files
.properties/release.properties

DevTools App User committed 5594e34 on Mon Jun 6 03:17:10 2016 -0400 description Released Build version ${env.MAJOR_VERSION}.${env.MINOR_VERSION}.98
 files
.properties/release.properties

DevTools App User committed 92915c9 on Fri Jun 3 11:16:04 2016 -0400 description Released Build version ${env.MAJOR_VERSION}.${env.MINOR_VERSION}.93
 files
.properties/release.properties

DevTools App User committed 17278e2 on Fri Jun 3 10:55:03 2016 -0400 description Released Build version ${env.MAJOR_VERSION}.${env.MINOR_VERSION}.91
 files
.properties/release.properties

DevTools App User committed c165306 on Thu Jun 2 14:43:33 2016 -0400 description Released Build version ${env.MAJOR_VERSION}.${env.MINOR_VERSION}.88
 files
.properties/release.properties
```

Problem is - commit ID **previous to 99214db** i.e **c165306** is getting displayed excluding the commit ID 99214db. I want the commit ID 99214db and its associated details also to be displayed.

Please help me where I'm wrong .Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^99214db`  means `--not` ([`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)): it excludes commits that are reachable from `99214db` (including `99214db` itself)

It would be easier to list all between `99214db`  and `8ce980e`:

[image: http://mythic-beasts.com/~mark/git-log-for-upload-smaller.png]

```
git log 8ce980e...99214db~
```

(see "[What are the differences between double-dot "`..`" and triple-dot "`...`" in Git diff commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6309)")

Comment: : Thanks for your input.
I modified my command as per your suggestion, as below

git log --pretty=format:"%cn committed %h on %cd description %B files" --name-only 99214db 8ce980e

instead of giving commit information b/n those range , its giving additional commit information too

Comment: @voltas yes, that is why I posted the picture about log range. Do you see the right commits at least?

Comment: If I want to restrict the information b/n 8ce980e and 99214db. How can I get it ? Thanks

Comment: I can see the entire commit ranges , from  beginning to end , but I would like to restrict it between 8ce980e and 99214db and its associated  commit details. Would like to take ur expertise here

Comment: Perfect, Thanks much..
+1 for your vivid explanation.

Comment: @voltas : Now i'm able to do a +1 .. crossed 15 reputation :)