# List files modified in a pull request within Travis

Tags: git, github, travis-ci, pull-request

I would like to list all the files modified in a pull request while on travis.

I tried `$(git diff --name-only $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH $(git merge-base $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH master))` but git doesn't know about  TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH since it's on a forked repo.

I also gave it a try with `git rev-list` and $TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE but it includes also the new commits on the master branch.

Any idea how to get the files that are modified exclusively by the PR?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are almost there.

There is no reason to use the environment variable `$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH` in this scenario.

The source tree within travis will be your pull request merged back into the most recent target branch (`$TRAVIS_BRANCH`, likely `master`). That is, `HEAD` is your pull request merged into `$TRAVIS_BRANCH`.

What you want are only the changes between your pull request and `master` which can be retrieved with

```
$(git diff --name-only HEAD $(git merge-base HEAD $TRAVIS_BRANCH))
```

or shorter with the dot-dot-dot notation

```
git diff --name-only HEAD...$TRAVIS_BRANCH
```

Thanks @ostrokach

It's also interesting to only take the modified and added files into account (and ignore deleted files) if you want to check the content

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM HEAD...$TRAVIS_BRANCH
```

Comment: There is a shorthand for this: `git diff --name-only HEAD...master` (with three dots). For more information, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/2063031).

Comment: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD...master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: You may want to replace master by $TRAVIS_BRANCH, such that it also works when the PR is made against another branch than master.

Comment: shouldn't it be `$TRAVIS_BRANCH...HEAD` instead, given HEAD has newer commits?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `$TRAVIS_BRANCH` as in the following command:

`git diff --name-only HEAD...$TRAVIS_BRANCH`

(as suggested by @Matthias Kuhn). But first, execute the following

```
$ git remote set-branches --add origin $TRAVIS_BRNACH
$ git fetch
$ git diff origin/$TRAVIS_BRANCH # now works as normal
```

This is needed to fix the following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD...master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

(as described in https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6069).

---

Using `$TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE` is also possible, but in case that
there changes in the destination branch of the pull request, they will be included as well. If this case is not likely in your case (for example, when only a single pull request to this branch can be created at a time), so this solution is easier.

The command is:

`git diff --name-only $TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE`

Comment: but isn't `git diff --name-only $TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE` also going to return the modified files on the branch we're pulling too?

Comment: I don’t understand what did you mean. As I see, it will return all the changes in commits that are about to be merged into the pull request destination branch.

Comment: I think it returns all the changes in the PR + all the changes on the branch that you don't have on your branch yet (more or less what has been pushed meanwhile to master or whatever branch)

Comment: Yes, in fact Ronyis's command is absolutely essential to solving problems on recent builds on Travis, since otherwise many commits are missing in the pulled copy.