# Git diff, which commit should I put first?

Tags: git

For example,

```
hash09  Update something5
hashNew Update something4
hashOld Update something3
hash03  Update something2
hash02  Update something
hash01  Add something
```

If I want to see what has beed introduced in hashNew, should I use

```
git diff hashNew..hashOld
```

or

```
git diff hashOld..hashNew
```

or

```
git diff hashNew~
```

or

```
git diff hashNew^
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git diff commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-dif)

Comment: `git show hashNew` will show what was introduced in hashNew

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
git diff hashOld hashNew
```

it produces the same output as:

```
git diff hashOld..hashNew
```

Keep in mind that:

- ^ – indicates the parent commit
- ~ – indicates the first parent commit

so, in order to use them to see what has been introduced in hasNew, you could write:

```
git diff hashNew~ hasNew
```

or

```
git diff hasNew^ hasNew
```

with

```
git diff hashNew^
```

you would be comparing the working directory with hashOld, since hasOld is the parent commit of hashNew

Answer (score 0):

To show what changes are introduced by a particular commit, `git show` is handy. More info at [man git-show](https://gitirc.eu/git-show.html).

For more information about the syntax, [man gitrevisions](https://gitirc.eu/gitrevisions.html) gives thorough explanations.