# Why does the base branch file (left hand side) of a Github Pull Request show different content than the HEAD version?

Tags: git, github

We have a branch "prod" into which a PR is going to be merged. The Left Hand Side of the "Compare" dialog thus should be showing the "prod" branch content.  It looks like this:

`<span class="file-name" [innerText]="row.ts | date:'MMM dd, yyyy, hh:ss a'"></span>`

However the "prod" branch content actually contains a formatting bug fix :

`<span class="file-name" [innerText]="row.ts | date:'MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a'"></span>`

This behavior is repeatable across multiple team members so it does not appear to be a browser caching issue.   Also this can be seen when running `git diff` from the command line using the three-dot syntax.

`git diff prod...prod-feature | grep hh`

Why does this happen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63892277/341994

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40413397/341994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question.  There are two main formats of diffs and they show slightly different things.

The `..` (two dot) version shows the difference between the version on the left and the version on the right.  In other words, `git diff A..B` (or just `git diff A B`) looks at the differences between A and B.

The `...` (three dot) version shows the differences in B, starting from the merge base of A and B.  In other words, as the manual page states, `git diff A...B` is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base A B) B`.

In your case, `prod-feature` is based off an older revision of `prod`.  The latter has progressed, and you're seeing the diff between the version of `prod` that `prod-feature` was based off, and `prod-feature` itself.

Now, you might ask yourself, why do we even have this three-dot functionality?  Because it shows differences only in one branch.  Since your `prod` branch has progressed, `git diff prod..prod-feature` would end up showing a diff that deletes the new data you've added in `prod`, when in fact the result of a merge will not do that.  In addition, it will add a tremendous amount of noise in many cases.  A three-dot diff makes it easier to reason about what changes will be added to and removed from the main branch when the feature branch is merged.

Comment: Tried this out: the double-dot version is what we want Can _github_ be persuaded to display the double-dot version instead of the triple?

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Consider reading the docs. https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-comparing-branches-in-pull-requests#three-dot-and-two-dot-git-diff-comparisons