# Show diff between branches using GitHub web interface

Tags: github

Is it possible to show diff between 2 branches using GitHub web interface?
Is it possible to show diff between 2 commits using GitHub web interface?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To show the difference between two branches, do the first step of starting a pull request. You can either use the UI interface on GitHub.com, or adapt this URL:

`https://github.com/<account_name>/<repo_name>/compare/<base-branch>...<compare-branch>`

To see differences between two commits you can adapt this URL (I do not know how to "click" myself to this):

`https://github.com/<account_name>/<repo_name>/compare/<commit-base-short-sha>..<commit-compare-short-sha>`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6889416) for a description of the difference between the `..` and `...` in the two URLs above.

Answer (score 2):

Select your branch and click on "Compare":

[image: Compare branches]

You will be able to select the branch to compare with.

Comment: What about diff between 2 commits? (I mean not between 2 commits, but more like between states at these 2 commits) As I understand I can just create branches from these 2 commits and use your method to compare branches, but is there more direct way?

Comment: See my answer for a more direct way to see commit diffs

Comment: I have checked this method to compare 2 branches and it gives me weird results, like highlighting diff of removed lines that are not presented in 1st and 2nd branches final state.

Comment: Actually (2 dots) `https://github.com/<account_name>/<repo_name>/compare/<base-branch>..<compare-branch>` is what I was looking for, and (3 dots) `https://github.com/<account_name>/<repo_name>/compare/<base-branch>...<compare-branch>` seems the same as if we use `Compare` from web interface and it produce 'weird' diff.

Comment: Yes, when comparing branches GitHub defaults to 3-dots. What is weird about it?

Comment: I am here 2023 and I don't see the compare button on my web interface for a branch. If you don't see the compare button, the links with both .. and ... still work: `https://github.com/<account_name>/<repo_name>/compare/<base-branch>...<compare-branch>`