# Do a complete compare with all commits

Tags: git

I have developer who has a branch which has a few changes that were for implementing a feature.

In a misunderstanding with how test data works. They tried to fix several tests that were fine. They did this over several commits to their branch, along with all the changes needing to implement this feature.

I want to do a full comparison of everything in the `main` branch, and the culmination of every commit they did for this `feature` branch.

Because of the misunderstanding, they have broken several tests, and even tried to change some logic in the code. I basically want a full set of the difference between `main` and `feature`. to go through by hand with them and undo changes line by line.

Unfortunately not everything would have a merge conflict. Is there a way to do this with git, or some way to make every change a merge conflict to simulate it?

Comment: If you want to view them without using a tool. `git diff main..feature` is the correct command with `git` alone.

Otherwise using vscode with a tool like gitlens here is the stackoverflow link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112526/how-to-compare-different-branches-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: If you are using GitHub (not sure if you are) then this is how you compare using their tool: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939962/show-diff-between-branches-using-github-web-interface/63940108#63940108