# Git New Tag is having older commits

Tags: git

I am new to this tag concepts. In main branch, i pulled the most recent commits with

```
git pull origin main
```

I pulled the remote tags with

```
git fetch --tags --force
```

Then, I created a tag locally

```
 git tag -a v2.2 -m "some message"
```

the problem is, when i checked the tags in VScode, the tag v2.2 is having the commits of v2.1. I want only the commits made after v2.1 to be present in the new tag. How can i do that ?

Comment: In Git, every commit points to the entire history leading up to itself, and tags point to commits; there’s no excluding the history of 2.1 from the history of 2.2. Instead, to see what’s new in 2.2, you should use 2.1 as a reference point – for example, if it were `git diff`, `git diff v2.1..v2.2`. What did you do to “check the tags in VScode”?

Comment: @Ry- If I do "git diff v2.1..v2.2" its showing the older changes which I commited before creating tag v2.1 as new changes.

Comment: @Ry- Thanks for pointing it out. in VSCode git source control, under tags section. anyways its solved

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add and commit first on your branch, *before* adding a tag.

If you tag right after a pull, you would tag the last fetched commit, which might be the one *already* tagged v2.1.

Don't forget, a tag references a single Git object (here a commit).
That commit, in turn, has a reference to a history of past commits (including the v2.1 one).

---

> - If I do "`git diff v2.1..v2.2`" its showing the older changes which I commited before creating tag v2.1 as new change

See "[What are the differences between double-dot "`..`" and triple-dot "`...`" in Git diff commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6309)"

`git diff v2.1..v2.2` will show you what is in v2.2, and what is not in v2.2 compared to v2.1.

Check first if v2.1 commit is a direct descendant of v2.2 commit (ie, if they are on the same branch).

> I made some commits (lets say 10 commits) in "Feature" branch , merged to "develop"(remote) via PR and then to "main" via PR(remote) from develop.
>
> Now I need to create a tag (v2.2). So I pulled the main, created a tag pushed it to remote. when I checked the diff between v2.2 and v2.1, but there are like 20 commits.

I would recommend:

```sh
git fetch
git tag -a v2.2 -m "some message" origin/main
git push --tags
```

That way, you are sure to tag what is from the remote `origin` you just fetched, rather than your local `main` branch, which would include local commits of your own, not yet pushed.

---

The [OP Hari Warshan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16081273/hari-warshan) clarifies in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285823/git-new-tag-is-having-older-commits/70286161#comment124293469_70286161):

> I had some other commits which wasn't there in remote.
> That is what caused the confusion.

Comment: Sorry if i sound dumb. I made some commits (lets say 10 commits) in "Feature" branch , merged to "develop"(remote) via PR and then to "main" via PR(remote) from develop . now I need to create a tag (v2.2). So I pulled the main, created a tag pushed it to remote. when I checked the diff between v2.2 and v2.1, but there are like 20 commits.

Comment: If depends if your local main had itself local unpushed commits when you `git pull`'ed origin/main to your main.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, i had some other commits which wasn't there in remote. thats what caused the confusion.

Comment: @HariWarshan OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.