# Github; compare doesn't show the same file as the one in the branch

Tags: git, github

So I have a main branch (2.1) which functions of a Fork of a repository, which I synch upstream.

From that I branched my own version (let's call it VR_2.1), which I want to manually keep up to date, because there are 2 config files which I change that I need to check before merging.

Now, the VR_2.1 config file when I browse to it via web it shows all the changes I pushed. However when I compare that branch to the normal synched 2.1 I get a completely different config, the default it looks like. How is this possible?

It is my first time Githubbing, :) I looked around but couldn't find it.
Tips are welcome, cheers

Comment: Because you are probably diffing with `..` locally. Try with `...` instead.

Comment: Explanation: `..` will do a straight diff between the 2 branches.... but your PR does _not_ show that because the base branch might have _moved_ so diffing like that would include changes _not_ related to your branch. So, to get changes only related to your PR, you need to use `...` which will use the latest common ancestor between the two branches and then diff *from there*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare two branches on GitHub, you'll notice the URL looks something like:

```
https://github.com/org/repo/compare/2.1...VR_2.1
```

Notice the 3 dots between the branches. This type of diff shows **changes in VR_2.1 since the two branches diverged**.

If you change the URL to use 2 dots instead of 3 (i.e. **2.1..VR_2.1**), you'll see the diff between these branches. You'll also notice the arrow between the two branch names changes from a ← to a ↔.

GitHub has [documentation on comparing commits](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/viewing-and-comparing-commits/comparing-commits)..

For more information on diff notations in git, including some helpful visual diagrams in the accepted answer, see [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git diff commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477)