# exclude files changed on base branch on git diff

Tags: git

I have 2 branches: main and other-branch

```
A -- B --> main
 \
   -- C -- D ... --> other-branch
```

- commit B -> changed a file called main.txt
- commits C, D ... -> change a file called other.txt multiple times

When I run `git diff --name-only other-branch main` it returns me both main.txt and other.txt, but I would like it to return only the diff to the common ancestor (C diff A), meaning it would exclude main.txt

Is there a way of doing that in a simple command?

Comment: Try triple dots: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/7976758 (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+triple+dots): `git diff main...other-branch` or `git diff other-branch...main`

Comment: I think you want `git diff --name-only main...other-branch` - this will show you the differences between `other-branch` (D) and the last common commit (A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to see the changes between the merge-base of main and other branch. The merge-base is `A` and can be obtained with command `git merge-base main other-branch`. Now you need to diff `other-branch` against `A`:

```
git diff "$(git merge-base master other-branch)" other-branch
```

This is a lot to type and very confusing. Luckily, Git has a convenient shortcut for exactly that task:

```
git diff master...other-branch
```