# What is Gitlab Compare API parameter straight meaning for?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-diff

In [Gitlab `Compare` API](https://docs.gitlab.com/14.10/ee/api/repositories.html#compare-branches-tags-or-commits), there is a parameter named `straight`.

What does this parameter do? Can you give some example?

Comment: It's the difference between [two dots and three dots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/7976758): `git diff foo..master` vs `git diff foo...master`. The docs for the parameter is quite clear.