# Bitbucket pull requests show previously committed changes that don't apply

Tags: git, bitbucket

With one of our repos, when we create pull requests to merge our develop branch to a release branch, we always see a lot of extra code changes that were already previously committed to develop, which we do not see when we compare branches at the command line using "git diff develop release-x.x.x"

Could this be a known bug in bitbucket or is this a common occurrence if there is an incorrect setting in our repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is probably just in your understanding of how the site describes a pull request. It uses a [triple dot diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-dif):

```
git diff develop...release-x.x.x
```

(And this makes perfect sense when you understand what a merge is; a pull request is, after all, a proposal to perform a merge.)

So obviously you are not going to see the same thing when you use a *different* command at the command line.