# How to see changed files after calling git fetch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-fetch

If two people are working on the same repository on github and the same branch master. Then say person A pushes their change to master and I as person B, how do I check the files changed in after calling `git fetch`?

If I do:

```
git fetch
git merge master origin/master
```

I get this line:

```
aa@DESKTOP-KQQ0A3T MINGW64 ~/..
$ git merge master origin/master
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 src/main.js | 16 ++++++++--------
 1 file changed, 8 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
```

I like how the diff in `src/main.js` is described in that way, but that info appears only when I merge, so my question is, what command should I use to see the same info about the diff but before doing merge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I answer at all, one quick note:

> ```
> git merge master origin/master
> ```

Please don't do this: you want just `git merge origin/master`, not `git merge master origin/master`.  (Fortunately you were *on* `master` when you ran this, so that Git ended up ignoring the `master` part.  If it had not, you would have seen `Merge made by the octopus strategy`.)

---

Let's answer this part first:

> I like how the diff in `src/main.js` is described in that way, but that info appears only when I merge, so my question is, what command should I use to see the same info about the diff but before doing merge?

To see what `git merge` would have said (assuming your work-tree is "clean" in that `git status` would say "nothing to commit"), run:

```
git diff --stat HEAD...HEAD@{upstream}
```

It's the `--stat` that produces the summary.  Let's hold off a bit on the arguments to `git diff` here; but let's note (because it is important) that this assumes a simple, ordinary single-merge-base-commit merge, or a fast-forward operation (these are very likely).

> how do I check the files changed in after calling `git fetch`?

This question itself reveals a bit of confusion (natural confusion, as Git is pretty confusing :-) ).  Specifically, *`git fetch` has not changed any files.*  What `git fetch` did was to obtain new *commits*.  Each commit is a snapshot—a copy of all files as they were at the time you made the snapshot—and a snapshot is not, in itself, a *change*.

At the same time, though, if you look at a snapshot with `git show` or `git log -p`, Git will *show* a change.  If a snapshot is a snapshot, not a changeset, how can Git show a *change?*  Well, after a bit of thought, the answer is obvious.  It's like one of those ["spot the difference" pictures / quizzes](https://www.google.com/search?q=spot+the+difference+pictures):

- Look at the *previous* snapshot.
- Then look at *this* snapshot.
- What changed?

That's how `git show` shows you a change-set, even though the commit is a snapshot.  The commit has a *parent* commit and Git just compares, with `git diff`, the parent `hash~1` or `hash^1`, with the commit whose hash is *`hash`*.  (The `~1` and `^1` suffixes both step back one first-parent in the Git graph.)

#### About `git diff` and its arguments

The `git diff` command is pretty complicated, so it can do more than just this, but to a first approximation, it simply *compares two complete snapshots*.  It does not matter how you name them:

```
git diff origin/master master
```

for instance will find the commit—the hash ID—that `origin/master` names, and the commit that `master` names, and then compare the two.  The output is a set of instructions: *This is how to change the first commit to make it look like the second commit.*

You can write:

```
git diff origin/master..master
```

if you prefer.  When you do this sort of thing with `git log`, you will often see many commits, not just two.  The `git diff` command is different: it just looks at *those two* commits.  In effect, it throws away the `..` part (except that they serve to separate the two names, of course).

When it comes to merging, there's another special `git diff` syntax: `git diff A...B` means `git diff $(git merge-base A B) B`.  That's what we are using above.  Normally, the three-dot syntax has a different meaning; `git diff` changes it to this particular "tell me what a merge would do" meaning, instead.

(This is not quite what `git merge` runs at the end *after* having done the merge, because after the merge completes, the merge base has changed.  And, if the merge base is not just a single commit, the `git diff A...B` syntax will pick one single commit anyway, and compare those two commits, while `git merge` will default to a more complex strategy.  Hence, *after* a true-merge finishes, Git can just run `git diff --stat HEAD^ HEAD`, which is essentially what it does.  For a fast-forward not-really-a-merge "merge", Git can run `git diff --stat HEAD@{1} HEAD`.)

For more on the normal and special Git-diff-only meaning of the three-dot notation, see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) and [the `git diff` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html).

Answer (score 4):

After your fetch you want to do:

```
git diff ..origin/master
```

The answer from rholmes here goes in way more detail:
[How to check real git diff before merging from remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944376/how-to-check-real-git-diff-before-merging-from-remote-branch)

Answer (score 1):

This command will help you:

```
git diff master:src/main.js
```

Looks like this question is partly duplicated by this topic:

[git: diff between file in local repo and origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101572/git-diff-between-file-in-local-repo-and-origin/21101644)

Comment: This is not it. after I do fetch, I want to see the diff ... because your code `git diff master:src/main.js` implies I would have to know about src/main.js but I don't. I'm only fetching, at that point I have no way of knowing which files are modified, so I need to know that after fetch

Answer (score 0):

For a quick look when you know which files you've touched you can also try:

```
git log —name-status HEAD..origin/master
```

this will give you a quick overview of your co-workers commits and which files were modified in that commit. If you notice that one of the files modified is also a file you are working on then you can go ahead and diff the file:

```
git diff master:src/main.js
```