# diff -r: limit recursion?

Tags: bash, shell, filesystems, diff, posix

Is there a way to specify the maximum recursion level for recursive diff `diff -r` (to compare two directories)?

What I'm trying to do is compare two projects on github (one was branched from another). I now suspect there may be a remote branch in one of them that links to the other, which will let me do a diff from `git`, however the question still applies to filesystems in general.

Edit-Update: This answer addresses how I might have `git` help me perform a comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5162839/340947

What's been happening is I have cloned both repos and I am calling `diff -r repoA repoB` and it reports differences in the `.git/` dirs, which is to be expected, yet I am uninterested in differences within these directories.

In this case it would be perfect to just show diffs between the first-level files in the directories, because this particular project does not have subdirs. If anyone has tips for how to compare two dirs while excluding particular folders (the `.git/` dirs in my case) that'd be great too!

Comment: If there are no subdirectories, doesn't `diff` work directly on the top-level files in the two directories, without `-r`?

Comment: @vergenzt I did not try that. That would be handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I'm not aware of any way of limiting the depth of recursion with `diff -r`.
2. You can exclude files that match a pattern with `-x PAT` or `--exclude=PAT`. So

   ```
   diff -r -x .git repoA repoB
   ```

   would be useful if you *did* want recursion.
3. In your case, just leave off the `-r` since you don't want it to recurse.

   ```
   diff repoA repoB
   ```

   already does what you want.