# Pulling Github repo back

Tags: github

I have created a git repo at github and cloned it at home:

```
 - eris:utility-functions$ ls
README

 - eris:utility-functions$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

 - eris:utility-functions$ cat .git/config 
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/dotancohen/utility-functions.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

 - eris:utility-functions$ git log --pretty=oneline
d444d752ed18b9d5b8422621b841413c30159d3c first commit
```

At work I have cloned the repo, made a few commits, and pushed back to github:

```
 - bruno:utility-functions$ ls
example-usage.php  README.md  solr.php  util.php

 - bruno:utility-functions$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

 - bruno:utility-functions$ cat .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = https://github.com/dotancohen/utility-functions.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master

 - bruno:utility-functions$ git log --pretty=oneline
cbfe00402226457aed50f658126783151b074759 get_user_ip_address(): Handle multiple addresses for all types
998d57e333d0a0700539f7c6c12b9bad5536b430 get_user_ip_address(): Handle multiple addresses
6ed9d43a05ab8f0a4191da84d8025db59095f8c3 Add function for sending mail with Amazon Simple Email Service
051c8e3f4982028cef677b486b305f3057be1be4 Added get_external_ip_address() which relies on simplesniff.com.
76e574f9260cae0f9fc00ed56b9b6da5f3f37c42 Provide example usage for ensure_fields() function.
39a6471627e1be6b0351257428e634c6f45dd234 ensure_fields(): Properly document ensure_fields(): Return NULL on invalid i
c0b06fb40b86cba67edafc1454df64e4e8e9c9a2 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/dotancohen/utility-functions
1aa18cbdef9643f3d964a97ccda41df414e009cf Added ensure_fields() function. Added example usage page.
63840793056ce75ac0e9b7dcbcd9683980a24a2c Added ensure_fields() function. Added example usage page.
5cf5aba1fd808433570c7e4c2693acf03a0de862 Initial solr.php file. Added solr_escape() function.
5e75c0499bc4b1fe1350577726b0566d7c647a8e Initial commit

 - bruno:utility-functions$ git push
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /run/user/dotancohen/keyring-wHsyrf/pkcs11: No such file or directory
Username for 'https://github.com': dotancohen
Password for 'https://dotancohen@github.com': 
Everything up-to-date
```

Now when I try to pull at home, I git is confused about the branch:

```
 - eris:utility-functions$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

I am wary of simply doing `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` as I'm not sure exactly what will happen to my current commits. **As I've never changed the branches on the home (eris) computer, what might cause the error? Is running the command `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` safe to do from home? Why didn't I have to do this from the work computer (bruno)?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master` master as I'm not sure exactly what will happen to my current commits.

Nothing will happen to your current commit on master.

A `git pull` will then fetch and merge `origin/master` to master.

If you wish, you can just `git fetch` first, and then [examine the diff between the two branches before merging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5162800/6309).
See [Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair)'s post "[git: `fetch` and `merge`, don’t `pull`](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/)"

> Why didn't I have to do this from the work computer (bruno)?

Probably because you did a `git push -u origin master` on the first push from work, which will set a remote tracking branch to (work) `master`.
See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)" for more details.