# Git diff on local verses remote if i have forgotten to branch?

Tags: android, git, repository

Supposing I have made a silly error of never branching after I fetched a remote repo. how would I go about getting a patch that covers all the changes I made on a local copy?

some time ago I did a

```
 $ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.3.1_r1
 $ repo sync
```

and brought down the 30Gb source of android, I was following a readme and didn't know about git at the time. So I then applied a bunch of patches and then made a bunch of changes myself. Only recently have I made a branch. And now I'd like to be able to create a set of patches that will make it possible for others to generate the head that I have locally. Is there anyway I can do this without fetching the whole repo again? I tried to use the answer on [giff cloned...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162800/git-diff-between-cloned-and-original-remote-repository)
 but it seems to be comparing me to the current version of android and not the -b 4.3.1 version. How do I incorporate this into that answer?