# SourceTree : see diff between local Repository and remote Repository?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have already seen the following question.

[git diff between cloned and original remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162800/git-diff-between-cloned-and-original-remote-repository)

My question is how can i see this diff result in SourceTree(not in shell!) ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is how you do this is SourceTree:

1. Make sure you have the branch that you want to compare checked out
2. On the sidebar find the corresponding remote branch
3. Right-click that remote and select *Diff Against Current*.

Comment: I am using v1.9.6.1 for Windows, and the Diff Against Current didn't do anything. (Update: Found out that I had not selected "All Branches" in the top window. When selected, it worked fine)