# How do I know the fork base of a project in github?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

[This](https://github.com/96boards/edk2) project is a fork of [this](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2). The fork has got 15,549 commits at the moment while the original one has 20,521 commits. Is there any easy way to know the commit in the original project which the fork is based out of?

The idea that crosses my mind is to clone both the repositories locally. Then pick-up each commit hash of the forked project from newest to oldest in order and try to find the same in the parent project. Is there a more elegant approach to achieve the same?

Comment: If all you need to do is find the common ancestor between two branches, then [this might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/find-common-ancestor-of-two-branches) to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the difference between two repositories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968512/getting-the-difference-between-two-repositories)

Comment: See also : [git-diff between cloned and original remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162800/git-diff-between-cloned-and-original-remote-repository)

Answer (score 0):

[Fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) is for repositories, not branches, therefore not just a single commit is the source. The whole repository is cloned.

Also, through pull requests the original can get updated from its fork, and if the fork has a longer lifetime, it gets update from the original as well.

[This](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) is how GitHub suggest syncing the repositories, you can use this to find the common code and the differences as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a local repo, with the two github links as remotes :

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tianocore/edk2
$ cd ed2k

# add second remote :
$ git remote add 96boards https://github.com/96boards/edk2
$ git fetch --all
```

You can then compare any itels from the two repos.

Branches in the first repo can be referred to using `origin/{branch name}`, branches in the second repo can be referred to using `96boards/{branch name}`.

For example, to find the common commit on branch master :

```
$ git merge-base origin/master 96boards/master
```