# How to detece differences between local file and a file in another repository in git

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a file in my local repo that I want to compare against a new version of the same file in another repo. I tried to do something like:

```
git diff origin/master https://github.com/ProjextX/prox.git client/src/main/ber/mainCode.java
```

but gave me `fatal: Invalid object name 'https'`

The file in `prox.git` is located in the same directory `client/src/main/ber`

Is the command that I'm using correct? If not, what is the best command to compare?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git diff between cloned and original remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162800/git-diff-between-cloned-and-original-remote-repository) - as the answer to that question says you can add any remote you want it doesn't need to be the original where the local copy came from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git only three commands could interact with remote repos: fetch/pull/push.
So, to use `diff` you should first download remote repo data locally and then proceed as usual. You could add a new "remote" as per link in a comment, or you could just fetch it into a default ref-name FETCH_HEAD:

```
git fetch https://github.com/ProjextX/prox.git
```

and then you could do as usual you do diffs between branches locally

```
git diff origin/master FETCH_HEAD client/src/main/ber/mainCode.java
```