# Is there a way to see all changed files on a branch in Git?

Tags: git

I apologise if this isn't very clear, but in Git, is there a way to see all changed files on a branch, by name only?

As far as I know, I can use `git log` to see files that have changed in a single commit, but I want to see all files that have changed since the branch was created, over several commits.

There is `git diff`, but this also lists the changed files in the branch I'm comparing to which I don't want to see. I kind of want a command that says 'show me file names for all changed files in this branch'.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Supposing you're on branch `foo`, and you're interested in which files have changed since the point when it diverged from `master`, you can just do:

```
git diff --name-only master...
```

(Note the three dots.)  If you're not `foo`, you can use the full form:

```
git diff --name-only master...foo
```

I made some graphics that explain the double-dot and triple-dot notations, and their differences between their meaning in `git rev-list` and `git log` - you can find them in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256249/git-diff-doesnt-show-enough/5257065#5257065).

Comment: Also worth noting that if you reverse the order branch names in the latter argument you can check for changes on the original branch (great for giving an indication of changes there before a merge)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that there is something that does exactly what you want based only on your current branch, but if you know the commit id that is the parent of your branch, you can do:

```
git diff --name-only <commit id of branch point>..HEAD
```

Comment: that is a good idea and one i thought about but I don't know how to work out which commit to compare to on the master when I created the branch. did that make sense?

Comment: You can use the triple-dot notation (e.g. `git diff A...B`) in order to compare between the merge base of `A` and `B` (which in most cases will be the branch point you're talking about) and `B`.  I've added a bit more about that in my answer.

Comment: What is the simplest way to determine the commit id of the branching point? Many of the examples assume it is master but it may not be if you've branched from another feature branch.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have checked out the branch you are working on, and you want to compare it to *master*:

```
git diff --name-only master
```

Comment: That does a diff between the tip of master and HEAD - the OP is asking about files that have just changed on the topic branch.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this command to find out the list of N files changed between two versions. Here N is 50.

```
git log  --pretty=format: --name-only <SourceBranch>...<TargetBranch> | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg | head -50
```