# 'git diff': Show only diff for files that exist in both commits

Tags: git

Is there a way to use `git diff` to get a diff between two commits, but only show the diff for the files that exist in both commits?

I have a branch I created a couple of weeks ago, and our main code has diverged quite a bit from it by now. As a result, if I do a diff between my current HEAD and the tip of the old branch, I get dozens of changed files, but it's mostly just noise.

I really want to see a diff that shows only the files that exist in both branches. I know one way to do this would be to cherry-pick the other branch's commits on top of the current HEAD, but is there a way to do it just using `git diff`?

Comment: @manojlds that is incorrect. a commit is not a snapshot of contents of the repository. A commit is a record of the changes to the content of the repository. A new file can exist in commit B which did not exist in commit A.

Answer (score 40):

The following may do what you want:

```
git diff --diff-filter=M commitA commitB
```

The `M` option to `--diff-filter` says only to include files that appear to be modified between the two commits - ones that only exist in one branch or the other would be selected with `A` ("added") or `D` ("deleted").

You can see which files would be selected with these letter codes by doing:

```
git diff --name-status commitA commitB
```

... and there's more information about all of that in the [`git diff` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful...it makes me see where my thinking was wrong.  What I really want isn't the files that differ (which is still a lot of files), but the diff for only the files that were modified in the old branch.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, I really want to see what changes would result if I applied the old branch as a patch atop the new branch.  Which is maybe what I should do, since it's easy enough to undo it.

Comment: @Kyralessa: this is a good question (and, I hope, answer :)) as it stands, so I'd suggest that you create a new question to ask about that.

Comment: Although I suspect that what you want is `git diff old-branch...new-branch` - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256249/git-diff-doesnt-show-enough/5257065#5257065) for an explanation of the `..` and `...` syntaxes in the context of `git diff`.

Answer (score 0):

The [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944973/457237), instead of showing modifications only in files that exist in both commits, shows a diff of *all* modified files in both commits.

Say, for example, one commit had two files modified and another has 1000. According to the question, the diff should contain two files or less, but the other solution shows 1002 files in the diff!

---

**Working Solution**

I couldn't find any existing `git` command to do this, hence I had to use a combination of existing commands.

First, let's define an alias `files` that gives us the names/paths of all files in a given commit like so -

```
git config --global alias.files 'diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r'
```

Now `git files commit_1` gives us all files present in `commit_1` and doing the same on `commit_2` gives us all files present in `commit_2`. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/457237) of why/how this command works.

Now, some command-line acrobatics -

```
sort <(git files commit_1)  <(git files commit_2) | uniq -d | xargs -d '\n' -n1 git diff commit_1 commit_2 > my_changes.diff
```

We are passing the list of files present in both commits to `sort` and then picking files common to both by passing the `-d` flag to `uniq` which picks only duplicates and finally invoking `git diff` on these common files via [`xargs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) and saving our diff into a file.