# 'git difftool' with only modified files

Tags: git

I have many new files as well as some modified files that I added to my branch, and when I do `git difftool master` it diffs all modified files as well as opening up for all new files. I see things like

> Launching WinMergeU.exe: /dev/null src/example1.cpp

It is rather annoying since it is somewhat pointless to looking at a diff of new files.

Is there a way to *only* have Git diff the modified files and ignore new files?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just tested [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944973/391161), and it appears to work equally well with `difftool`.

```
git difftool --diff-filter=M
```