# Why did the Git "source" change from "refs/heads/qux" to "refs/remotes/origin/qux"?

Tags: git

The following commands reveal what I just did:

```
Z:\www\gg\web\tests\sample-repo-cloned>git log --all --source --graph
* commit ce7ae79a2b993b780002dbc5eac650fa49427df0       refs/heads/qux
| Author: myname <myemail@gmail.com>
| Date:   Sun Sep 25 00:24:42 2011 +0300
|
|     qux another
|
* commit ef2ea79f40d8e77e47cba31954ef2093c534cc17       refs/heads/qux
| Author: myname <myemail@gmail.com>
| Date:   Sun Sep 25 00:15:56 2011 +0300
|
|     qux
|

Z:\www\gg\web\tests\sample-repo-cloned>git branch
* master
  qux

Z:\www\gg\web\tests\sample-repo-cloned>git checkout qux
Switched to branch 'qux'

Z:\www\gg\web\tests\sample-repo-cloned>notepad2 qux.txt

Z:\www\gg\web\tests\sample-repo-cloned>git add qux.txt

Z:\www\gg\web\tests\sample-repo-cloned>git commit -m "qux more stuff"
[qux 1d18327] qux more
 1 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

Z:\www\gg\web\tests\sample-repo-cloned>git log --all --source --graph
* commit 1d183278e78b8896d882822dacb4aad5bb8cf1bd       refs/heads/qux
| Author: myname <myemail@gmail.com>
| Date:   Sun Sep 25 00:39:06 2011 +0300
|
|     qux more
|
* commit ce7ae79a2b993b780002dbc5eac650fa49427df0       refs/remotes/origin/qux
| Author: myname <myemail@gmail.com>
| Date:   Sun Sep 25 00:24:42 2011 +0300
|
|     qux another
|
* commit ef2ea79f40d8e77e47cba31954ef2093c534cc17       refs/remotes/origin/qux
| Author: myname <myemail@gmail.com>
| Date:   Sun Sep 25 00:15:56 2011 +0300
|
|     qux
|
```

My question is this: why did the first two commits change their "source" from `refs/heads/qux` to `refs/remotes/origin/qux`? They did that after the third commit. I don't understand this. What's the logic behind that "source"? It seems to be changing randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--source` parameter to `git log` is just a bit confusing, I'm afraid.  It means that each commit will be shown with the ref by which it was found - it doesn't mean that it will list *all* refs that contain that commit.  In your case, the hypothetical output of a similar option that included all of refs that contain that commit would be:

```
* commit 1d1832       refs/heads/qux
| Author: myname <myemail@gmail.com>
| Date:   Sun Sep 25 00:39:06 2011 +0300
|
|     qux more
|
* commit ce7ae7       refs/heads/qux refs/remotes/origin/qux
| Author: myname <myemail@gmail.com>
| Date:   Sun Sep 25 00:24:42 2011 +0300
|
|     qux another
|
* commit ef2ea7       refs/heads/qux refs/remotes/origin/qux
| Author: myname <myemail@gmail.com>
| Date:   Sun Sep 25 00:15:56 2011 +0300
|
|     qux
```

... and you can confirm that by browsing the history with `gitk --all`, or trying `git branch -a --contains ef2ea7`, etc.

So, all that's happening is that when you ran the `git log` the second time was that it checked the `origin/qux` remote-tracking branch first, and then the `qux` branch that you're working on.  As to why that order should be different between the two invocations, I'm afraid I'm not sure.

The remote-tracking branch is one behind since you haven't updated it via a `git push` or a `git fetch`.

Comment: Could this be used as a way to identify whether some commit exists only locally?

Comment: @rFactor: Absolutely: `git log qux ^origin/qux` (or its [equivalent form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256249/git-diff-doesnt-show-enough/5257065#5257065), `git log origin/qux..qux`) will show you all the commits in `qux` that aren't in `origin/qux`.