# Comparing and merging modified files in github

Tags: git, github

I worked on the master branch of a repository and I didn't commit the files for a while. By this time, most of the files have been modified. How can I compare and merge the files in git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit your files first, in order to diff them to `origin/master`.
If you don't want to commit them on `master` (because you might want to update `master` by rebasing it on top of `origin/master`), you can create a `tmp` branch a commit there first.

```
git checkout tmp
git add -A
git commit -m "intermediate commit"
```

Then you need to `git fetch origin/master`, supposing origin points to your GitHub repo

Finally, you can:

- Check all commits done on remote branch since when local branch was created:

```
    git diff HEAD...origin/master
```

- ee the differences of what you have on your local branch but that does not exist on remote branch run:

```
    git diff origin/master...HEAD
```

See [Mark Longair's excellent answer on `git diff`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257065/6309) for more.