# diff current working copy of a file with another branch's committed copy

Tags: git

I have a repo with file `foo` in the master branch. I switched to bar branch and made some changes to `foo`. How can I now run a `git diff` between this copy (which isn't committed yet) and the copy of the master branch?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

The following works for me:

`git diff master:foo foo`

In the past, it may have been:

`git diff foo master:foo`

Comment: Each time I see an answer of yours regarding `git diff`, I always think of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256249/git-diff-doesnt-show-enough/5257065#5257065

Comment: @VonC: thanks, it's nice to know it was worth drawing those :)  Incidentally, do you happen to understand the oddity I updated my answer with?

Comment: Did you try with a `--` in order to separate parameters from path arguments? `git diff -- master:foo foo`

Comment: @VonC: if I do that (`git diff -- master:foo foo`), then I just get the same as `git diff foo`, or `git diff -- nonexistent foo`, for that matter.  Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: I just ran across the same problem, but in my case `git diff foo master:foo` gives the fatal error and `git diff master:foo foo` is the working version! Typing `--` makes them both work. Any explanations yet?

Comment: On 1.8, `git diff -- master:foo foo` doesn't work - it seems to treat the arg `master:foo` as a non-existent filename (and ignores it) instead of a file-in-a-branch. Try switching the last 2 args - if it worked, the diff comparison should be reversed, but the output doesn't change.

Comment: For me it's the opposite -- I can do `git diff master:foo foo` but not vice versa. I don't understand it either. With git 1.7.9.5 / Ubuntu 12.04 I can at least do `git diff -R master:foo foo` to get the diff I actually want. When I try that with msysgit 1.9.4 / Windows 7 x64 I get `fatal: unable to read 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. Without `-R` I get the same error message as you with git 1.7.9.5, but with 1.9.4 I get `fatal: master:foo: no such path in the working tree`.

Comment: 2nd version (`git diff master:foo foo`) worked for me (git version 2.6.2, OS X 10.11.1).

Comment: You need to explicitly specify branch or commit for both files: `git diff branch1:foo branch2:foo` or `git diff HEAD:foo master:foo`

Comment: this answer fails to work today ... instead see answer below from @JordanBrough

Comment: I think I found the magic: `git diff master:foo -- foo` works for me.

Comment: In bash, you can also do `git diff {master:,}foo` if you do not want to write the path twice.

Comment: `master:... no such path in the working tree.`

Answer (score 133):

You're trying to compare your working tree with a particular branch name, so you want this:

```
git diff master -- foo
```

Which is from this form of git-diff (see the git-diff manpage)

```
   git diff [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree
       relative to the named <commit>. You can use HEAD to compare it with
       the latest commit, or a branch name to compare with the tip of a
       different branch.
```

FYI, there is also a `--cached` (aka `--staged`) option for viewing the diff of what you've staged, rather than everything in your working tree:

```
   git diff [--options] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>...]
       This form is to view the changes you staged for the next commit
       relative to the named <commit>.
       ...
       --staged is a synonym of --cached.
```

Comment: Thanks.  No idea why, but only this answer worked for me with git 1.8.1 in Linux.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I got hung up on wanting to include the name of my current branch in the diff command, but I see that's not needed.

Comment: This worked for me a few months ago, but doesn't seem to be now. Currently I'm at git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66); I don't know what I had before.

Comment: @hBrent this still works for me on OSX 10.11 with git 2.7.3.  Here's a quick sample repo with instructions if that's helpful: https://github.com/jordan-brough/git-diff-test/

Comment: Thanks @JordanBrough.

Comment: Works well for files that are in subdirectories of project.  Other suggested methods don't find files unless  you write out whole path.

Answer (score 20):

```
git difftool tag/branch filename
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me for comparison between a local working copy of a file, and that file version in a remote repo (not "origin"). Thanks, Adir and Baz

Comment: `git difftool` has no `-v` option according to docs https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool. Did you mean `-y`?

Answer (score 15):

Also: `git diff master..feature foo`

Since `git diff foo master:foo` doesn't work on directories for me.

Comment: Me neither. Is it a Windows thing?

Comment: @ScottStafford I'm on Ubuntu, so no, it doesn't seem it's just a Windows thing.

Comment: Works for me as long as I explicitly give both branch names (windows)  `git diff branch1:foo master:foo `

Answer (score 10):

```
git diff mybranch master -- file
```

should also work

Comment: This only works for files committed to mybranch, not current working copy of the file.

Comment: what does "--" mean above

Comment: This allows compare in both directions: `git diff deployment master -- file` and `git diff master deployment -- file` are work as expected **with any 2 branches**.

Comment: @Pushparaj "--" is an optional separator between the rest of the command and the path to the file.  This can be useful to avoid ambiguity, for instance if you had a file and a branch with the same name.

Answer (score 10):

What also works:

```
git diff master ./relative-path-to-foo
```

Answer (score 6):

To see local changes compare to your current branch

```
git diff .
```

To see local changed compare to any other existing branch

```
git diff <branch-name> .
```

To see changes of a particular file

```
git diff <branch-name> -- <file-path>
```

Make sure you run `git fetch` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a branch named `master` and a branch named `feature`, and you want to check a specific file called `my_file`, then:

1. `git diff master..feature /Path/to/my_file` shows the diff between the commited versions of `my_file` on branch `master` and `feature`.
2. `git diff master -- /Path/to/my_file` shows the difference between the working directory (the un-staged files) and the branch `master` of `my_file`.