# Cannot git diff. File exists in both branches but getting "fatal: Path '...' exists on disk, but not in 'master'"?

Tags: git

This is what I get when trying to compare a file between a branch and master:

```
git diff gamemodes/terrortown/entities/entities/ttt_c4/shared.lua  
         master:gamemodes/terrortown/entities/entities/ttt_c4/shared.lua

fatal: Path 'gamemodes/terrortown/entities/entities/ttt_c4/shared.lua' 
       exists on disk, but not in 'master'.
```

Here is the file on master:

```
$ git log -n 1 -- gamemodes/terrortown/entities/entities/ttt_c4/shared.lua
commit d0241471298ce617b68dcf268be1c0af0cf8170c
Author: me
Date:   Fri Jan 1 23:25:17 2016 -0600

    December 2015 Update
```

And here is the file on my branch real_disarm:

```
$ git log -n 1 -- gamemodes/terrortown/entities/entities/ttt_c4/shared.lua
commit 84a7de46b92b8747cf98a57a8f7101682377980e
Author: me
Date:   Sun Jan 10 00:27:33 2016 -0600

    Remove trailing whitespace
```

Obviously the file exists in both branches. The whole reason I'm comparing the files is because I'm trying to remove trailing whitespace so that my patches don't give annoying "warning: squelched 5 whitespace errors warning: 10 lines add whitespace errors." output.

Comment: Does `git diff ..master -- gamemodes/terrortown/entities/entities/ttt_c4/shared.lua` has the same issue?

Comment: I never before seen this way of using `diff` command. I can't see it [in documentation too](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

Comment: @MarekR [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9113407) is where I got the comparison functionality from.

Comment: That seems to have worked @VonC! Do you mind if I ask what `..master` means? I know that `--` indicates an end to command arguments. Also, if you put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find different ways to compare a file with itself from another branch in "[How can I compare files from two different branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4099742/6309)".

In your case:

```
git diff ..master -- gamemodes/terrortown/entities/entities/ttt_c4/shared.lua
```

See [Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair)'s answer about "[What are the differences between double-dot “..” and triple-dot “…” in `git diff` commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6309)"

`..master` will show the difference between the *tip* of the current branch (`HEAD`) and `master`.