# git compare commit ID between branches

Tags: git, diff

I need to find the different between two branches by commit ID, not by files. I mean, the commits which are not in one branch. How can I do it.

I fires, `git diff branch1...branch2`, but, it gave the files different, I need commit ID differences.

Comment: Did you look at `git cherry`?

Comment: `..` and `...` have different meanings in `git log` and `git diff` - the diagrams [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5257065/223092) may make that clearer, if you excuse me plugging one of my answers...

Comment: If you need to do this in GitHub - [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49838096/820410)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
git log branch1...branch2
```

And optionally, we can give inner module[directory] of the project.

For example, want compare the commits in the `module/admin` directory, you can try like this.

```
git log branch1...branch2 module/admin
```