# Diffing two branches to show changes introduced in one branch

Tags: git, diff

I know about `git diff branch1 branch2`. However, I would like to see changes introduced in one branch only. I can get this functionality with:

```
git checkout branch1
git merge branch2
git reset origin/branch1
git diff
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do:

```
git diff branch1...branch2
```

(note that there are three dots)

... which will show you all the changes introduced on `branch2` since it diverged from `branch1` (or, strictly speaking, since the merge-base).  The different uses of `..` and `...` in `git diff` and `git log`, can be a bit confusing, so you might find the diagrams in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257065/223092) helpful.

Comment: Hello sir. Nice answer. I see from your track record that I'm playing with the big boys trying to compete on git answers... :-)

Comment: @Alex: Well met, sir! I hope you're well. As it happens I'm only occasionally checking the git tag at the moment, but it's certainly a good one to follow

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the hash of the most recent common root of the two branches, for which you use git merge-base:

```
git merge-base branch1 branch2
```

Then after than you can get a log of the changes from that common root to the branch head with git log:

```
git diff <common base hash>..branch2
```

Comment: This is almost correct. I used `git diff <common base hash>..branch2`. instead of `git log ...`. Can you update your answer? Then I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Vlad. All done. Although Mark has provided a more concise answer. I'd give him the tick instead!