# Git: reviewing changes to a branch

Tags: git

When performing a code review my approach is to use meld to view the changes to the branch:

**Step 1**. Using git log to find the sha1's of the first and last commits on the branch

```
git log --graph --oneline --all
```

This will give something like:

```
    * fffffff Another commit to HEAD
    * eeeeeee A commit to HEAD
    | * ddddddd The last commit on branch MY_AWESOME_CHANGE
    | * ccccccc Some work
    | * bbbbbbb First commit on branch MY_AWESOME_CHANGE
    |/  
    * aaaaaaa Updated comments to explain aggregation of External Data
```

**Step 2**. Use git difftool to launch meld to view the changes

```
git difftool aaaaaaa ddddddd
```

My question is: 
Is there a better way to go about step 1? The following question provides a way to find the branch start point: [finding-a-branch-point-with-git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git). I can then use "git log" to find the sha1 for the last commit on the branch:

```
git log -1 MY_AWESOME_BRANCH
```

But it seems overkill and I wonder if I'm missing something simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `...` (triple-dot) syntax to `git diff` or `git difftool`, as in:

```
git difftool master...experiment
```

What this does is to show you the difference between:

- The *merge base* of `master` and `experiment`
- ... and `experiment`

The meanings of `..` and `...` are different for `git log` and `git diff` - [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257065/223092) of mine has some diagrams that show the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on `HEAD`, then

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff MY_AWESOME_CHANGE
```

will show you all the changes which **would** be merged onto your `HEAD`, and will update your working copy appropriately, but won't actually commit the merge.

Comment: That will stage the result of the merge, though, which is undesirable in this situation, particularly if you already had some changes in the index.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by "will update your working copy appropriately".