# Why does "git log --name-only" show one file change, but "git diff" shows more?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

When I run

```
git log --name-only
```

it shows sha1 and sha2 as consecutive commits and only one file was changes in sha2.

However, when I run

```
git diff sha1 sha2
```

it shows differences in a lot of files. Why is this?
sha1 and sha2 are consecutive commit ids that I got from git log --name-only.
sha1 is the earlier commit.

I thought that `git diff` would only show differences in files that are listed by `git log --name-only`.

The `sha1` and `sha2` are consecutive commits in the same branch.

`sha1` was a cherry pick from `B1` and `sha2` was cherry picked from `B2`.

I found that a file that was not listed in `git log --name-only` was modified and basically my changes in `B1` were overwritten by `B1` commit, even though it isn't listed as having been modified.

Is there an issue with the cherry-picking here where changes are picked up unknowingly?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256249/git-diff-doesnt-show-enough/5257065#5257065

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `git-log` call to

```
git log --name-only sha1..sha2
```

Comment: I forgot to clarify, sha1 and sha2 are consecutive commit ids when I ran git log --name-only.
Though when I ran it that way, I got a longer list of commits.
It just seems odd that one command shows them as sequential commits and another shows more changes in between.

Comment: That's the thing: without the dots, it just shows *all* commits reachable from these two commits, right up to the very first commit.

Comment: I'm not sure why I don't get any notifications when someone responds, but looks like my understanding of git log needs to be expanded.
Thanks Michael.