# How to know which files were changed from the forking - git

Tags: git, git-fork

Suppose I create a branch, I make some commits, how do I get the files and the commits changed from the fork ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would give you the list of modified files between one branch (master for instance) and another:

```
 git diff --name-status master..branch
```

But that would take into account the latest modifications from master as well.
If you want the difference between the moment you have branched and the latest of your new branch, then:

```
 git diff --name-status master...branch
```

See "[git diff doesn't show enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256249/git-diff-doesnt-show-enough/5257065#5257065)":

[image: diff dots]

Similarly, to list just the commits done since you have branch:

```
git log master..branch
```

Note that **fork** is more reserved to *cloning* (on the server side) and not so much used for branching.

Comment: Note that if master has also moved on, you should replace `master` above with the branch-point commit

Comment: Thank you but is it possible to compare changed files between the beginning and the head of the same branch ?

Comment: @user1611830 that is why I mention `git diff --name-status master...branch`: with three dots, you only get between the beginning and head of your branch.