# Compare committed revision with server one for the same branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-diff

There is a basic question about revision compare in git. I can compare current version with original version with

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD
```

However, I need compare current version (`origin/master`) with current version of same branch on git server. It was pushed after get my original version. I tried to compare via commit id (got from web gitlab interface). However, there was the following error:

```
$ git difftool 866f426ce3c4d7594500ce322b68fd1d96ced06b
fatal: bad object 866f426ce3c4d7594500ce322b68fd1d96ced06b
```

---

There is an advice to use

```
git diff masterbranch remotebranch
```

For my case it looks like:

```
git diff master origin/master
```

In this case the diff is a comparison current version with original version I got as start for my changes. However, this branch was changed later. I would like to compare my version with actual state of branch `origin/master` not original one I used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [compare local git branch with remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/compare-local-git-branch-with-remote-branch)

Comment: Thank you. However, both revisions are in same branch (`origin/mastet`)

Comment: `git diff master origin` will works

Comment: Thank you. However I have got `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to do that:

1. directly diff with the remote server (need to be connected):

   `git diff masterbranch remotebranch`

   for instance

   `git diff master origin`
2. Grab the code and diff localy :

   - do a fetch (the syntax is the same as git pull, but it doesn't automatically merge)
   - do a diff between your dest branch and the other branch
   - then do a merge if you want

Comment: You may want to quote that second part since you copied it from [git diff between remote and local repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11935678).

Comment: Thank you! (+1) Actually, the first way doesn't, because it's compare previous revision of the branch I used as start. The second approach works, but if it is possible, I would prefer way without uncontrolled code change like `git fetch` does.