# Git: How to check whether a local branch has any commit that the tracked remote does not have?

Tags: git

Need to do this in a script. Thank you.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/compare-local-git-branch-with-remote-branch).

Comment: [`git-wtf`](http://git-wt-commit.rubyforge.org/git-wtf) is a cool handy script which does this already. It is written in ruby. You could try to reverse-engineer it.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following command (as an alias) to list all local commits not pushed to the remote repository.

```
log --oneline --decorate=short --graph --all --branches --not --remotes
```

This will need to be modified for use in a script, and there are probably plumbing commands that do the same thing, but I find it useful.

The key is in the last few arguments:

- `--all` includes all refs in `refs/` -- you may not want this if you are only wanting the commits for the current branch.
- `--branches` includes all refs in `refs/heads` -- leave it off for current or specify a branch explicitly to limit the list of commits.
- `--not --remotes` contains the magic -- making sure none of the commits listed are in `refs/remotes`.

**Edit >**  It looks like the `git rev-list ...` plumbing command has similar arguments, but I have not tested it to know if it works the same.  Plumbing commands are recommended for scripting, so have a look at it -- [man-page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) for reference.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the situation is like this :

```
      /--a--b--c  myBranch [local branch]
     /
----x <- [closest common ancestor]
     \
      \--e--f  origin/myBranch [tracked remote]
```

- `git status` will display a message `myBranch..origin/myBranch [ahead 3, behind 2]` - `ahead 3` means your local branch is 3 commits ahead of the closest common ancestor, `behind 2` means the remote branch is 2 commits ahead of the closest common ancestor
- `git log origin/myBranch..myBranch` will display the log about commits `a-b-c` - it will display the log for the commits ranging from the common ancestor of the two branches up to `myBranch`
- `git log myBranch..origin/myBranch` will display the log about commits `e-f` - it will display the log for the commits ranging from the common ancestor of the two branches up to `origin/myBranch`

You can add any option you like to these commands, e.g : `git log --oneline --decorate origin/myBranch..myBranch`

Answer (score 0):

`git status` indicates how far the current branch is behind the tracked branch. You can run this in a script and parse the output. There might also be a plumbing command that gives you the information a little more directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the latest change information using the **'git fetch'** command and then if you do a '**git status'** on a tracked branch, it should show you the number of commits that's not  pushed to the server or how far the current branch is behind.

Using **fetch** command wouldn't apply the changes in you local branch,for this, you have to merge it using **'git merge origin/branch_name'**.