# How do I see my local unpushed commits?

Tags: git, git-svn

If I have a local branch `test` and the remote branch is `test`.
So if I did a push it would be `push origin test:test`

How can I see my local unpushed commits that I did on that branch?
`git log`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/compare-local-git-branch-with-remote-branch is what you are looking for, I believe

Comment: chk out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3338774/556856 Works like a charm.

Answer (score 13):

I generally use `gitk --all` for that (after a `git fetch --all`).

And, for console mode, I have an alias of `git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline` which gives a nice and compact overview of your branches. In particular, it shows what you can push.

For both these commands you can specify branches (`test origin/test` in your case) instead of showing them all with `--all`.

Comment: That `git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline` is incredible. My mind is blown.

Answer (score 10):

First fetch the remote's changes to your local repository:

```
git fetch origin test
```

This will place all commits from the remote's `test` branch in `origin/test`.  Now you can use `git log`:

```
git log origin/test..test
```

That will show all commits on `test` that are not reachable from `origin/test`.