# Why does git rev-list fail to detect remote / origin changes?

Tags: git, bash

I'm trying to build a reliable "repo ahead and behind" signal for my bash prompt. Despite reading source code for many git prompts (shell, python scripts) and reading many stack overflow answers, I could not figure out why comparing

```
$ git rev-list HEAD..origin/master
```

did not actually compare master at the origin. Figured it out, so I decided to ask this question and answer it so it's not buried and will immediately answer someone else's similar question.

Answer (score 2):

It finally dawned on me that origin/master is just a *local* "pointer", which makes sense with git's distributed nature. It really threw me until I remembered this. Almost none of the answers about comparing local and remote repos comes right out and says that you must do a fetch. Finally found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/compare-local-git-branch-with-remote-branch). Anyway, I have [parrt's git bash prompt](https://github.com/parrt/bash-git-prompt) working in a very reliable way. To determine whether your repository is behind the origin, do this:

```
$ git fetch origin mybranch
$ git rev-list HEAD..origin/mybranch
```

This is expensive so my bash prompt script does it every 30 minutes to see if I'm behind remote repo.