# Check and download difference.

Tags: github

I want check github repo and if is difference - download it. 
How I can make it?
I will write bash script for it, but I can not find information about repo difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a local repo linked to a GitHub remote repo which might have evolved, you can download and [compare the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1801150/6309) with:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git fetch
git diff master origin/master
```